# REST request using Volley sends back a result that is different from Postman

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using the [GenericRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley/31638943#31638943) (an extension of the built-in jsonrequest) to make a REST call to a server that takes in a json object and returns a string, which is "0" if the json object already exists and a nonzero string otherwise.

However, with the following code, I always get a "0" back no matter what I sent.

```
    JSONObject userobj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        userobj.put("email",email);
        userobj.put("password",password);
        userobj.put("username",name);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, userobj.toString());

    GenericRequest jsonObjReq = new GenericRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, String.class, userobj,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Handle access token.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Register received: " + response);
                    long token = Long.parseLong(response);
                    if(token == 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Received 0!");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.registerfail_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Register success!");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.Welcome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

    };

    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    helper.add(jsonObjReq);
```

When testing in Postman, given the input like: 
{
  "email": "dlee23122",
  "password": "1234",
  "username": "dlee23122"
},
it gives back a nonzero string. (Screenshot as follows.) But when given a slightly different input using the Volley, it keeps giving back a "0". What could be the reason?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: take a screenshot of your postman http heards or add them here. postman is not a true REST client.

Comment: @Vahidhashemi Hi, thanks for helping. The screenshot of Postman has been added. The header is "Content-Type":"application/json".

Comment: Turns out this is a problem of what mentioned in [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022133/how-can-i-delete-the-namevaluepairs-key-from-the-jsonobject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i faced the same problem, volley default connection timeout is set to **5 sec** and it was posting two times, so check for time in postman on right side, if it is closer to 5000ms or greater this might be the problem.
**My problem got solved by adding the following to Volley request:**

```
DefaultRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
   jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
```

if you want set custom retry policy look at this post [Change Volley timeout duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration)