# raw string in post request body using retrofit

Tags: java, retrofit

i want to send user:user in the **post request** body. I am using **retrofit** lib. please suggest me.

I have tried already like this

```
@POST(/login)
void login(@BODY String s,Callback<LoginResponse>)
```

And called this as

`login("user:user",Callback<LoginResponse>)`

Answer (score 6):

Use a TypedString for the body instead of a String.

Comment: thanks. If i want to send raw integer means can i mention as Integer or int?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do? How about trying it, and then let us know if it fails, and how it fails?

Answer (score 1):

**Method #1**

Consider your "user:user" is seem to a JsonObject. So please post JsonObject instead of Raw String.

You can construct a POJO class:

```
public class User{
    public final String user;

    User(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Your method like this:

```
@POST(/login)
void login(@BODY User user,Callback<LoginResponse>)
```

And call this as:

```
User user = new User("john");
login(user,Callback<LoginResponse>)
```

Since Retrofit uses Gson by default, the User instances will be serialized as JSON as the sole body of the request. Default use content-type:**application/json**

**Method #2**

You just can post Raw String as Form Data with content-type:**application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and just need a **@FormUrlEncoded** annotation.

Here is your method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(/login)
void login(@Field("yourkey") String user,Callback<LoginResponse>)
```

you just need to replace "*yourkey*" to your api's key - "*user*"

Call this as:

```
String user = "john";
login(user,Callback<LoginResponse>)
```

**Reference**:
[How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423093/3171537)
[retrofit.http.Field](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Field.html)
[retrofit.http.FieldMap](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/FieldMap.html)