# How to post array parameters with Retrofit?

Tags: retrofit

I want to `post` data as follows:

```
   {
     "user_id":"14545646",
    "list":["4545645","4545645","4545645","4545645"]
   }
```

I used the following `Retrofit` method:

```
interface DeleteOrder {

         @FormUrlEncoded
         @POST("/api/shop/deleteOrder.json")
         void getPoJoDeleteOrder(@Field("user_id") String user_id, @Field("list") String[] list,Callback<PoJoDeleteOrder> callback);

      }
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request

Answer (score 2):

if have many user,then use `FieldMap`.

user[0][email]=***&user[0][password]=***&user[1][email]=***&user[1][password]=***

```
@POST("/user/sign_in")
```

**User login**`(@FieldMap Map<String,String> fields)`;

```
    Map<String,String> fields = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i=0;i<users.size();i++) {
        User user= users.get(i);
        fields.put("user["+i+"][email]",user.email);
        fields.put("user["+i+"][password]",user.password);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This way it will send arguments like this

```
project_id=986&remark=testing&details=detail_1....
```

If you want to send array in JSON format, you need to add [] to array name.

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/projectLost")
    public void projectMarkLost(
        @Field("project_id") int projectId,
        @Field("lost_project_reasons[]") ArrayList<Integer> lostProjectReasons,
        Callback<JsonObject> cb
    );
```

That way you can check the array parameter with is_array($arr) and then iterate it.
[Source link.](http://johnsonsu.com/android-retrofit-posting-array/)

Answer (score -2):

If the list of query parameters is fixed you can do this:

```
@POST("/user/sign_in")
User login(
    @Query("user[email]") String email,
    @Query("user[password]") String password);
```

Otherwise, with the `map` you'll need to set the full query parameter as the key:

```
values.put("user[email]", "foo@bar.com");
values.put("user[password]", "123456");
```

This answer is copied straight from: [Github Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/565)