# Cannot deserialize object with gson.fromJson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to deserialize an object send with postman using gson.fromJson.

```
 @POST
    @Path( "company" ) // takes name as a path parameter
    @Produces( "application/json" ) // response formatted as JSON
    public Response insertCompany(String content) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CompanyWithNoIdReturn newCompany = gson.fromJson(content,  CompanyWithNoIdReturn.class);
   }

public class CompanyWithNoIdReturn {

     private final String name;
     private final String description;
     private final String logo;

    public CompanyWithNoIdReturn(String name, String description, String logo) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {

        return description;
    }

    public String getLogo() {

        return logo;
    }

}
```

The error that comes up is: javax.servlet.ServletException:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1

I understand that it means that it expects it to begin with `{` and not `"`as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1). Though what i have not understood is how do i fix it?

The json was contructed like this: [image]

EDIT: While using **form - data** the content is like:

```
content = (java.lang.String) "------WebKitFormBoundaryUG5yy1gW9G2V5qcz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CompanyName"

newCompanyName2
------WebKitFormBoundaryUG5yy1gW9G2V5qcz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Description"

newDescription2
------WebKitFormBoundaryUG5yy1gW9G2V5qcz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="logo"

newLogo2
------WebKitFormBoundaryUG5yy1gW9G2V5qcz--
"
```

Comment: Where is your input JSON?

Comment: @Amila i have added an image of postman\

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect body (content variable) in JSON format. But according to your image of postman your are sending `form-data`.

Try to switch to `raw` and insert this:

```
{
    "name": "Company name",
    "description": "Company description",
    "logo": "logo"
}
```

Comment: You are correct. It works fine. Though if i wanted it to work with form - data or xxx-www-form-urlencoded how could this be done?

Comment: If you are using framework it make sence to look into documetation. It should have classes for it. But I don't know what you are using and could not recommend anything. But in case of `form-data` your `content` should be similar to "name=a&description=b&logo=c" and you can parse it using `String` class.

Comment: I am not using any framework though i did not understand. If i use the code as in my initial question it produces an error cause it expects an object not a String. Can you write the code processing the data as i have written in my initial question?

Comment: post the value of your `content` variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process form data with a JaxRs service, you should look at [@FormParam](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html). Your service would become

```
@POST
@Path( "company" ) // takes name as a path parameter
@Produces( "application/json" ) // response formatted as JSON
public Response insertCompany(@FormParam("CompanyName") String name, @FormParam("Description") String description, @FormParam("Logo") String logo) ) {
    CompanyWithNoIdReturn newCompany = new CompanyWithNoIdReturn(name, description, logo);
    return Response.ok(newCompany).build();
}
```

You have to ensure that the names specified as in the FormParam annotations match the fieldnames  in your form.