# retrofit gson JsonSyntaxException parsing issue begin object

Tags: android, json

Error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

POJO:

```
LoginResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private Integer status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private User user;
}
```

- Create Pojo class User details  showing json object data 
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

```
 class User {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
}
```

My Json Output like

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "You are successfully logged in.",
    "data": {
        "id": "10",
        "email": "abcdef@gmail.com",
        "password": "3f009d72559f51e7e454b16e5d0687a1",
        "mobile": "abc@gmail.com",
        "verified_saller": "",
        "first_name": "abc@gmail.com",
        "middle_name": "abc@gmail.com",
        "last_name": "abc@gmail.com",
        "image": "",
        "default_size": "0",
        "wallet": "",
        "status": "active",
        "otp": "",
        "updated": "2017-10-28 12:22:21",
        "created": "2017-10-28 11:41:14"
    }
}
```

create interface for retrofit Api parsing

`@POST("user/login")
        Call<LoginResponse> userLogIn(@Body User login);`

- Main Activity code below Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

  APILogin service = ApiClient.getClient().create(APILogin.class);
          User login = new User();
          login.setEmail(email);
          login.setPassword(password);

  ```
      Call<User> userCall = service.userLogIn(login);
      userCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
              User user = response.body();
              mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              mcardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              //onSignupSuccess();
              Log.d("onResponse", "" + response.body().getMessage());
              if (response.body().getStatus() == 1) {
                  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                  Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                  startActivity(i);
                  finish();
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
              mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              mcardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              call.cancel();
              Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your network connection and internet permission" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
          }
      });
  ```

Comment: You Please Read First **[ask]**

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

Comment: share you json response

Comment: see this example.https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: where are you pass your username and password??  @Body User this model does not contain your username and  password filed

Answer (score 1):

Create an HttpResponseModel class as fllow.

HttpResponseModel.java

```
public class HttpResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    public int status;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    public String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    public User user;
}
```

And your Retrofit onResponse will be like

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(Call<HttpResponseModel> call, Response<HttpResponseModel> response) {
    HttpResponseModel httpResponseModel = response.body();
    if (httpResponseModel != null) {
        if (httpResponseModel.getResponse() != null) {
            if (!httpResponseModel.getResponse().isJsonNull()) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<User>() {
                    }.getType();
                    User user = gson.fromJson(httpResponseModel.getResponse(), type);

                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Please let me know if you still find it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> `JSON string you can tell from the error message that it is not the correct structure to be parsed into your Ad class.`

From your error   i can tell  that it is not the correct structure to be parsed into your  class.

`Gson` is expecting your `JSON` string to begin with an object opening brace. e.g.  **`{`** not with  **`"`**

> make your `JSON` Response with  correct structure from back end

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("user/login")
    Call<LoginResponse> userLogIn(@FieldMap Map<String, String> credentialMap);
```

create Map of username and password like below:

```
     Map<String, String> credMap = new HashMap<>();
     credMap.put("Username", "vishal.halani");
     credMap.put("Password", "vishal1212");
```

call like below:

```
 Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.userLogIn(credMap);
call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {


            if (response.isSuccessful()) {


LoginResponse loginResponse= ((LoginResponse) response.body());

            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());


        }
    });
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 61 path $.data

Comment: {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "You are successfully logged in.",
    "data":  [ ]
}