# Spark - Apply a function to a column of a dataframe without UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know how to apply a function to a column of a dataframe using a UDF.  However, the function I want to create accesses an external service.  Basically, it submits the text via REST API and then adds a new column of the response.  It's not recommended to use UDF's when accessing external services.  In fact, I am getting sporadic errors when I attempted to do it using a UDF.

What is the best practice to achieve this?  I don't think my question is code specific, but I will add some below as an example:

```
val entityDf = df.select(col("Text"),
                            col("coordinates"),
                            col("LocX"),
                            col("LocY"))
                            .withColumn("TextClass", functionUdf(col("text")))
```

I should add the error that I am getting when I attempt to use this function as a UDF here, just in case I am looking for a solution to the wrong problem:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$5: (string) => string)

```
def testFunc(text: String): String ={
    val gson = new Gson()

    val result = Http("url")
      .postData(f"""postdata""")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
      .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000))
      .asString

    val rootJson = gson.fromJson(result.body, classOf[rootNerJson])

    if(rootJson.classes.length > 0){
      return rootJson.classes(0).label
    }

    return "Null"
  }

val functionUdf = udf[String, String](testFunc)
```

Edit:  Stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$5: (string) => string)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1075)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:144)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedProjection.apply(Projection.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedProjection.apply(Projection.scala:30)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$22.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1147)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$22.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1142)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1142)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1141)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
>       at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
>       at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2832)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:644)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:603)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:612)
>       at OCRJson$$anonfun$main$1.apply(OCRJson.scala:112)
>       at OCRJson$$anonfun$main$1.apply(OCRJson.scala:24)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
>       at OCRJson$.main(OCRJson.scala:24)
>       at OCRJson.main(OCRJson.scala)
>   Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:922)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:836)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:808)
>       at OCRJson$$anonfun$main$1.OCRJson$$anonfun$$ner$1(OCRJson.scala:69)
>       at OCRJson$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$5.apply(OCRJson.scala:78)
>       at OCRJson$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$5.apply(OCRJson.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:92)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:91)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1072)
>       ... 87 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
>       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
>       ... 97 more

Comment: can you show the stacktrace of the exception? I could imagine that it's very slow/ineffcient to call the webservice for every row ... is `text` unique? Otherwise you could also add some caching mechanism

Comment: Yes, I added the stacktrace above.  And yes, text is unique.

Comment: Well, I think I've realized the error was from within the UDF, but this still isn't the right way to be doing this type of process right?  The service call is what makes me nervous about moving forward, even though it's working right now.

Comment: use of udf function seems approprite for your case. Your real problem is not udf function but the result you get in your request and the gson library not able to parse it. look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1

Comment: Change `val functionUdf = udf[String, String](testFunc)` to `val functionUdf = udf(testFunc _)`

Comment: Does that just change the parameter and return to Any?