# How can i resolve exception BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $ in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

I am trying to register a user with an API and after successful registration i am expecting a user id like [234] in response. But i am getting the mentioned error.Registration part include 13 fields including edit text,checkbox,and a spinner.the problem is occurred when i am trying to get the timezone value from API and populate it with a value.

i just stuck at this conversion and don't know where i am doing wrong.`enter code here`
                `

Comment: post the json response from the API

Comment: post your json here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

Comment: Which line you are getting the error. Kindly post the log and json structure

Comment: this is the response i am getting when i am posting it in postman with parameters.but problem is that when i am pressing the signup button it should send this response in the emulator too instead i am getting the error which i asked .@ManojPerumarath[
    793
]

Comment: @Jaymin it shouldn't be .i am just a newbie to retrofit.i think i have done wrong with my code .please help me out.

Comment: first, check your API on the postman. I think your response is not the right format.

Comment: @ShivaKanumala No,the response is ok.thats what i want to get. but when i am registering through emulator in studio it is not showing me the id .

Comment: okay. then check in your mobile device. because it's easy to find whether the problem is coming only emulator or all.

Comment: @ShivaKanumala same error.

Comment: for onResponse you write this line 'if(response.code()==200){   Log.d("message", "" + response.message()); }'

Comment: Few things you need to understand before posting question on StackOverflow. 1) You posted only code that you've tried. 2) There's no API sample (explanation) like expected params, response format etc in your question. (Not all people are aware of all the APIs) 3) If you get errors care to log it properly and post it along with your question. 4) Comments are meant to ask clarification, suggest improvements and not for extended discussion. If you take care these things, it'll be helpful us to help you ASAP. Moreover it save a lot of time. Good luck

Comment: API =https://www.moremovies.com/service/register_user.php?
parameters - fname, lname, email_id, password, mobile, madd, madd_from, newsletter, address, office_no, company, website, timezone   all above parameters are compulsory- in newsletter you have to show checkbox and pass parameter 0 or 1 , here 0 means yes and 1 means no

- "madd" you will have to get MAC address of Android device in backend and send to server at the time of signup and in "madd_from" you will be sending "Android", each Android device should have unique MAC address
  @Shashanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your json will be different. you need to fetch json response from server based on **objectType** but getting string.

You used **robopojo** plugins for pojo class generate.

then pass response class into post api.

For example ..

```
public class ResponseData {

@SerializedName("code")
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("error_message")
private Object errorMessage;
@SerializedName("data")
private List<Datum> data = null;

public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public Object getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(Object errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```