# How to POST data with retrofit and get the response in proper format?

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I am getting the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

when called a POST request.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418787/5705721) answer my json response do have the curly braces {}.

first my json response was-

```
{
    "status": {
        "status": "1",
        "message": "Entry inserted successfully"
    },
    "data": {
        "date": "24-Mar-2226",
        "month": "March",
        "party_name": "mark"
    }
}
```

then I combined the two separate objects in a single response object-

```
{
   "response": {
       "status": {
           "status": "1",
           "message": "Entry inserted successfully"
       },
       "data": {
           "date": "24-Mar-2226",
           "month": "March",
           "party_name": "mark"
       }
   }
}
```

but still I am getting the same error.

The GET request with retrofit is working fine but not the POST request.

This is my POST query-

```
  @POST("AddEntry")
    Call<ResponseClass> addMyEntry(@Body DetailsClass details);
```

Comment: I have added the json response from postman in the question

Comment: sry i want to see what your sending in your details Log that details

Comment: Please post the code of where are getting the response

Comment: sorry but I am not understanding exactly what  you want @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that a property you marked with String type but in the JSON it is an object.

With the JSON is:

```
{
   "response": {
       "status": {
           "status": "1",
           "message": "Entry inserted successfully"
       },
       "data": {
           "date": "24-Mar-2226",
           "month": "March",
           "party_name": "mark"
       }
   }
}
```

You should have some classes as below:

```
public class Response {
 @SerializedName("status")
 public Status status;

 @SerializedName("data")
 public Data data;
}

public class Status {
 @SerializedName("status")
 public String status;

 @SerializedName("message")
 public String message;
}

public class Data {
 @SerializedName("date")
 public String date;

 @SerializedName("month")
 public String month;

 @SerializedName("party_name")
 public String party_name;
}
```

Comment: I do have the same classes

Comment: I tried clean and rebuild project and also Invalidate Caches/Restart, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below class structure.

This problem is common for most of developer just understand structure and move on.

```
public class ResponseData {
 @SerializedName("response")
  public Response response;
 }

  public class Response {
 @SerializedName("status")
 public Status status;

 @SerializedName("data")
 public Data data;
}

public class Status {
 @SerializedName("status")
 public String status;

 @SerializedName("message")
 public String message;
}

public class Data {
 @SerializedName("date")
 public String date;

 @SerializedName("month")
 public String month;

 @SerializedName("party_name")
 public String party_name;
}
```