# Response error :: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, gson

I am making user authentication in android. i am passing username and password but this error appears. API is working fine any help will be appreciated
Can anyone tell i am doing wrong

**This is the the error that i am getting in android**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**LoginActivity**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {    
     private String email,password;
    private EditText emailET;
    private EditText passwordET;
    private Button loginButton,createAccount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    emailET = findViewById(R.id.editTextUname);
    passwordET = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    createAccount = findViewById(R.id.createaccountButton);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            userAuth();
        }
    });

    createAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,SignUp.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private void userAuth() {

    VidlyEndPoint vidlyEndPoint = RetrofitInstance.getService().create(VidlyEndPoint.class);

    email = emailET.getText().toString();
    password = passwordET.getText().toString();

    JsonObject requestBody = new JsonObject();
    requestBody.addProperty("email",email );
    requestBody.addProperty("password",password );

    Log.e("Response", String.valueOf(requestBody));

    //        User user = new User(email, password);

    Call<User> call = vidlyEndPoint.authUser(requestBody) ;

    final Intent dash = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),dashboard.class);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Response NS :", String.valueOf(response.code()));
            }

            else if(response.code() == 200){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(dash);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Response error :", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}


}
```

**Expected output:**
JSON TOKEN

Comment: problem is in your response. You are telling retrofit that you'll get a successful response of User, but actually is the Token

Comment: It's beacause you're asking response as User model (Response<User>),  so it's checking for email and password, but it's getting string, So change Response type to Response<String>.

Comment: @AhsanAbdullah If it helps, Please mark it as an answer or upvote .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonSyntaxException Gson: Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007127/jsonsyntaxexception-gson-expected-begin-object-but-was-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, with String response not User

```
Call<String> call = vidlyEndPoint.authUser(requestBody) ;

    final Intent dash = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),dashboard.class);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Response NS :", String.valueOf(response.code()));
            }

            else if(response.code() == 200){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(dash);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Response error :", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get This exception because you want an `object` in response but the actual `response` you got is a `string`.

You have to change your `server response` as JSON or your `response type` in `API` service as String.

Answer (score 0):

Replcae `Response<User>` with `Response<ResponseBody>`.