# After pressing button getting json response error in android

Tags: android, json

[image]

Hi in the below error is coming when am trying to parse the JSON object as a string.

When Am sending JSON object to server

Json request:

```
{"name":"Building 1","level":1}
```

Json Response:

```
{"status":"success"}
```

Below one is edited code with the response. But, I am not getting any response from the server.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

API service = retrofit.create(API.class);
try {
    JSONObject parmobject=new JSONObject ();
    parmobject.put("name",name);
    parmobject.put("level",level);
    Call<NewBuilding> userCall = service.getbuildinglist (parmobject.toString ());
    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<NewBuilding> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewBuilding> call, Response<NewBuilding> response) {
            if (response != null && response.code ()==200) {
                JSONObject obj = null;
                try {
                    obj = new JSONObject (String.valueOf (response));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON:");
                }

                String status = response.body ( ).getStatus ( ).toString ( );

                if(status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success")){
                    makeText(getActivity (), "Building successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    arrayList.add (name);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                }
            } else {
                makeText(getActivity (), "Please try again for Adding New Building", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewBuilding> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace ();
        }
    });
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418787/10883621) ?

Comment: Because it it not getting json object

Comment: How to pass without " "

Comment: you are getting error for sender JSONObject or Reponse JSONObject.

Comment: it says you are getting non-JSON in response

Comment: @TejasPandya not getting any response from server

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

Comment: You've created model class that which you defined Jsonobject.but in your case now getting String="" instead of Jsonobject={}

Comment: yes.............

Answer (score 0):

You can add interceptor for what responses you are getting.

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

In retrofit

```
if (postService == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(base_url)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);

        }
        return postService;
```

Then you can see in verbose in log all the responses will be seen.

in response

```
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<NewBuilding> call, Response <NewBuilding> response) {
      try {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        Integer response1= obj.code();



      } catch (Throwable tx) {
        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + json + "\"");
      }
      }
```

Logcat:

> W/System.err: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
>       W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
>               at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1409)
>               at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593)
>               at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
>       W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:205)
>               at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
>       W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
>               at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223)
>               at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
>               at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
>       W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: "{\"name\":\"abv\",\"level\":\"1\"}"

Comment: try String status = obj.getStatus ().toString (); instead of  String status = response.body ( ).getStatus ( ).toString ( );

Comment: Provide what is in the response from server (see in verbose) and write what error are you getting now

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of log of verbose. it would be much help

Comment: please check it out and let me know

Comment: what about the server response (that will be given by interceptor)

Comment: shared a screenshot

Comment: {
    "status": "success"
}