# Retrofit onFailure in Sign APK

Tags: android, retrofit

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
            HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(Constant.TYPE, ApiClient.makeTextRequestBody(String.valueOf(Constant.TYPE_STORE)));
            map.put(Constant.DEVICE_TYPE, ApiClient.makeTextRequestBody(Constant.ANDROID));

            Call<AppSetting> call = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class).getAppSettingDetail(map);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<AppSetting>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AppSetting> call, Response<AppSetting> response) {//AppSetting.java response api
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(response.body()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " onResponse: "+"response.successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Utilities.printLog("MainActivity", "check app key --" + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                        if (response.body().isSuccess()) {
                            //     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " onResponse: "+"response is successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if (parseContent.parseAppSettingDetails(response)) {
                                if (PreferenceHelper.getPreferenceHelper(MainActivity.this).isForceUpdate() && checkVersionCode(response.body().getVersionCode())) {
                                    openUpdateAppDialog(response.body().isIsForceUpdate());
                                } else {
                                    /** option if user still login go to home else go to RegisterLoginActivity.java **/
                                    goToActivity();
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AppSetting> call, Throwable t) {
                   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Retrofit", "Retrofit: onResponse not called, onFailure called instead... ");
                    Log.d("Retrofit", t.getStackTrace().toString());
                    Log.d("Retrofit", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: explain your question in detail. see  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The Problem is when build apk with debug everything is ok, all jason display properly. But when build apk for release the retrofit goes to onFailure, with null json data. can any body help me on this

Comment: The Throwable.getMessage() ="Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"

Answer (score 0):

You could add `setLenient` to your `GsonBuilder()` like the following.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

**Note:** Make sure you have `gson` dependency in your `gradle`.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Comment: when do that throwable = "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" why??

Comment: for that exception see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418787/4854891)

Comment: when create Gson its goes to com.google.gson not com.google.code.gson

Comment: but still throwable = "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

Comment: You are getting the wrong response from your `API`. You are getting a `string` in response but it should be `object`. It can be happened due to many reasons. Better check your `API` in `Postman` and be sure that your `API` works fine and gives you a `JSON` in response.

Comment: for your info the json return when using postman like: {
    "success": true,
    "message": 321,
    "is_use_referral": true,
    "is_verify_email": false,
    "is_verify_phone": false,
    "is_document_mandatory": true,
    "is_login_by_email": true,
    "is_login_by_phone": true,
    "is_login_by_social": true,
    "is_hide_optional_field": true,
    "is_profile_picture_required": true
    "
}

Comment: To see your `request info` and `response code`,  please add `Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "Request info: "+ call.request())` and  `Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "Response code: "+ response.code())` inside `onResponse` and add `Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "Request info: "+ call.request())` inside `onFailure`.  and let me know.