# Send json raw object Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Hello I'm trying to send raw json through object to server without success with Retrofit library.Tried some recommendation from this question but not success [How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request/21423093#21423093) 
So my code is:

```
        Prod tag = new Prod();
        tag.setName(name);
        tag.email(email);

        String json = JsonUtilFactory.getJsonUtil().toJson(tag);
        TypedJsonString in = new TypedJsonString(json);

        service.checkProduct(in, new Callback<Object>()

  @PUT("/api/scans")
public void request(@Body TypedJsonString typedInput, Callback<Object>   callback);

 public class TypedJsonString extends TypedString {
    public TypedJsonString(String body) {
        super(body);
    }

    @Override public String mimeType() {
        return "application/json";
    }
}
```

So in every when I make request to server I got error like this

```
     D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP PUT https://somehost.com/call
D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json
D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 125
D/Retrofit﹕ {"name":"prod_name","email":"my@email"}
 D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (125-byte body)
I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/14/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
28418-28855/co.otenti D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-28 21:53:18.768      735-831/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed co.otenti/.activity.MenuActivity: +9s186ms
 D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 404 https://somehost.com/call (933ms)
 D/Retrofit﹕ Server: nginx/1.6.2
 D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Thu, 28 May 2015 18:53:20 GMT
D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 D/Retrofit﹕ Transfer-Encoding: chunked
D/Retrofit﹕ Connection: keep-alive
 D/Retrofit﹕ X-Powered-By: Express
 D/Retrofit﹕ X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 D/Retrofit﹕ Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AJagAmIPjbhpZwojw6AatazyL.ZKrtIC31UyHVSyBuN98pvYTaW9I%2BpeNr5XnEDS8yWrw; Path=/; HttpOnly
D/Retrofit﹕ Vary: Accept-Encoding
 D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
 D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1432839199295
 D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1432839199483
 D/Retrofit﹕ Cannot PUT /api/scans
```

Can some one explain ,e what I'm doing wrong?

Also previous code looked like this

```
  JSONObject obj = JsonFactory.toJson(prod,Prod.class)

        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString()));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Comment: 404 should indicate that your url is wrong, and not have to do with the actual content that you send

Comment: the url is okey. I can make request with DefaultHttpClient  and everything is works

Comment: yeah you was right.The problem was in url.

Comment: You can send Json Raw data using HashMap. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28712275/2362301) to answer.