# Convert POJO to JSON Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Is there any simple way in `Retrofit` to convert passed object to `JSON` automatically?

This is my Retrofit interface :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/places/name")
void getPlacesByName(@Field("name") String name,
                     @Field("city") String city,
                     @Field("tags") Tags tags,
                     Callback<PlaceResponse> callback);
```

At first I thought that if I pass `Tags` object it will be automatically converted to `JSON` , but in reality request looks like this : 
`name=pubs&city=London&tags=com.app.database.model.Tags%4052aa38a8`

Is there any simple way to convert `POJO` to `JSON` in `Retrofit`?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request. You need to define a @Body parameter and feed it a POJO.

Comment: I've tried that but if I use `@Body` I will get this error `@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding`

Comment: If you use @Body you should remove the FormUrlEncoded annotation Retrofit will do the rest.

Comment: or override the `toString` method of your object to return a json representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jackson to convert it directly to a String:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Or use Gson: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately cannot do it simplier

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a URL with parameters because you're using the `@URLEncoded` and passing the parameters as `@Field`.

Here is the solution:

```
@POST("/places/name")
void getPlacesByName(@Body RequestObject req, Callback<PlaceResponse> callback);
```

Additionaly, I would advise on using `@GET` for retrieving objects. `@POST` is used for creating an object and `@PUT` for updating. Although this isn't wrong, it as recomendation in order be `RESTful` compliant.