# Retrofit get body of request

Tags: android, serialization, gson, retrofit

I want to get the content of request object after it serializes passed object. I want to uderstand how retrofit serilizes my object.

```
@POST("/RegisterNewDevice")
public void registerDevice (@Body Device device, 
    retrofit.Callback<ResultBooleanResponse> callback);
```

How retrofit will represent my Device object? Let's say it is defined as follows:

```
public class Device {
    private int id;
    private String deviceName;

    //... constructors, getters and setters ...//

}
```

Because of https connection used for my services I cannot intercept it easily.

Comment: If you've included Gson in your dependency, Retrofit will use that to serialize your POJO.

Comment: Ok, but will it go as is into the body of request? Based on that I'm building a service and it does not work. The same request made with external tool, works as expected.

Comment: I suggest you go through this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)

Answer (score 0):

I think the @SerializedName should help you. 
Remember you can only use request body when your request is POST, PUT type.

```
public class SampleRequestBody {
    @SerializedName("param1")
    final String param1;

    @SerializedName("param2")
    final int param2;

    // public constructer
}
```

If your request is GET, DELETE, .. type, so you should use @Query

```
@POST("/abc/def")
void methoName(@Query("param_name") String param, Callback<type> callback);
```

Comment: I need content of the body of HTTP/HTTPS request. I want to see how exactly it serializes my information. If there is a dot, if there is a bracket ... and so on. The problem actually was with https connections so I had to write a small servlet to se exactly the content but from retrofit only I did not figured out how to do that.