# Retrofit 2.0 POST method with body is String

Tags: android, retrofit

This question may have been asked before but with new version 2.0 I did not find any correct answer yet.

My problem as below:

```
public interface  AuthenticationAPI {

    @POST("token")
    Call<String> authenticate(@Body String  body);

}
```

Then I call:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(authenUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        AuthenticationAPI authen = retrofit.create(AuthenticationAPI.class);


        try {
            Call<String> call1 = authen.authenticate(authenBody);
            call1.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    Log.d("THAIPD", "Success " + response.raw().message());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("THAIPD", " FAIL " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("THAIPD", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then I receive the response as `protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request`, That means my body parameter was not correct.

When I try to make a request by other tool as Postman I get the correct result with code is 200.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request) but with `Retrofit 2.0` I can not find TypedString class.

Here is the result when I try by another tool (DHC)
[image]

Comment: Did you set any content type ??  try setting the proper content type .
Can  you share your post man request and response ??

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @sreekumar . I had upload the image of postman, please help more.

Comment: Just one question, since you are doing oauth authentication and authorization, do you have to put the oauth parameters in the body? Normally they should be in the headers

Comment: @Dimitri : this is first step, it's authentication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Retrofit2.0 has now own [converter-scalars](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars) module for `String` and primitives (and their boxed).

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars
```

---

You can write custom `Converter` and Retrofit repository has a own `String` Converter implementation sample: [ToStringConverterFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/07d1f3de5e0eb11fb537464bd14fdbacfc9e55a7/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit/ToStringConverterFactory.java)

```
class ToStringConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
  private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("text/plain");

  @Override
  public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> fromResponseBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
    if (String.class.equals(type)) {
      return new Converter<ResponseBody, String>() {
        @Override public String convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
          return value.string();
        }
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override public Converter<?, RequestBody> toRequestBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
    if (String.class.equals(type)) {
      return new Converter<String, RequestBody>() {
        @Override public RequestBody convert(String value) throws IOException {
          return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, value);
        }
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and related issue are tracked [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1151).

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's help me for resolving the problem in sending request. But I my response is an Json object and I also want to convert it to my Java model.
So how can I do with same converter ?

Comment: You can call `addConverterFactory()` multiple times for  `ToStringConverterFactory` and `GsonConverterFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to write a custom [Converter](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/index.html)

Something like this

```
public final class StringConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

public static StringConverterFactory create(){
    return new StringConverterFactory();
}

@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> fromResponseBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
    return new ConfigurationServiceConverter();
}

final class ConfigurationServiceConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, String>{

    @Override
    public String convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(value.byteStream()));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        return total.toString();
    }
}
}
```

and add this using addConverterFactory

Comment: in current version of retrofit (2.0) I can not see that the interface converter as: public interface Converter<F, T>

So can you have a look again?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the Converter interface doesn't exist in 2.0? I'm using 2.0 as well, can you double check?

Comment: Converter interface is exist in 2.0 but its type is Converter<F, T> not Converter<T>

Comment: Ah, Sorry, I think I was using beta1, it seems like it has changed in beta2. But anyway the implementation should be very similar. ;)

Comment: Hi, I just created a version for beta2, please have a try.

Comment: 1 thing to remember is the order of adding converter factory matters. you want to have something like: retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() .client(OkHttpClient) .baseUrl("base url") .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory().addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(getM‌​oshi()).asLenient()) .build();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but you are missing a "/"

```
@POST("token")  --->  @POST("/token")
```

Comment: thank you for you support, guy. But it's not the problem in my case :(