# How to pass string in 'Body' Parameter of Retrofit 2 in android

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit2

```
@POST("api/login")
Call<ApiResponse> loginUser(@Body String user);
```

Here the string is actually a JSONstring i.e.

```
{"email":"test@gmail.com","password":"test"}
```

Couldnt figure out what is wrong in this. Either the string it again converted to json. Please suggest..

This is what i want to do to my request as shown in picture.

[image]

Comment: is that json the response? What's the content of ApiResponse ?

Comment: No that is not the response. This data is to be sent to @body to get the response.

Comment: I am not sure if you can send JSON like that. I guess it would be converted again. Please see my answer they way I am using it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Convert your data in object

```
public class Credentials
{
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

Set the data to object

```
Credentials loginCredentials = new Credentials();
loginCredentials.email = "test@gmail.com";
loginCredentials.password = "password";
```

Call your api

```
@POST("api/login")
Call<ApiResponse> loginUser(@Body Credentials credentials);
```

Comment: I dont want to use 'data model' class to send the json to the body. I m searching for alternative.

Comment: @RanjanaDangol Ok then convert this make `JSON` using `GSON` and saved it in `String`

Comment: @RanjanaDangol: Wasn't mentioned in you post. Nevermind.  :D

Comment: mm.. I tried with GSon converting string to json data, but it doesnt work. is there any other way to pass string such that it would be taken as a json for @BODY .

Comment: @RanjanaDangol: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request/21423093#21423093

Comment: with retrofit 2 you need a model class. No workaround for that. @Rohit5k2 do you mind me asking why  `Credentials` is serializable ?

Comment: @Blackbelt: Nothing specific to this question. If you read my comment on the question post then you will find out this model class is kind of copy paste of my own projects model class (Not the whole part). My project requires it to be serializable. :D. Guess I should remove it because its not relevant to this question.

Comment: I have user model class with other elements too. For this request, I only need email and password, Do you have any way to just send two of the data in custom object class as a @BODY in retrofit.

Comment: @RanjanaDangol: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @RanjanaDangol Data model is the way to go if you are not using. then you are denying basic facts :D

Answer (score 23):

```
@POST("api/login")
Call<ApiResponse> loginUser(@Body HashMap<String, String> user);
```

We can use Hasmap here like this.