# Retrofit 2: 400 Bad Request when having body

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit2, put

I am trying to perform a status update PUT request. The following example returns 200 in Postman:

**URL:**

> http://www.example.com/users/3/status?seId=1&dt=2016-11-01T00:00:00Z

**HEADERS:**

> Content-Type:application/json
>
> charset:utf-8
>
> Authorization:Bearer LONG_TOKEN_HERE

**BODY:**

> { "status": 1 }

This is the structure of my Retrofit 2 request:

```
@PUT("users/{id}/status")
Call<Void> updateEventStatus(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                             @Path("id") int id,
                             @Query("seId") int seId,
                             @Query("dt") String dateTime,
                             @Body Status status);
```

The request's URL is the same as in Postman and so are the headers, so I suspect it is related to the body. `Status` is just a wrapping class with a single int field named `status`, which I created by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082962/5280641) (I did the same with credentials and it works well). I also tried making the status in body of type `int` but it results in Bad Request as well.

Any idea what could be the difference between the Postman request and the Retrofit 2 request? Thanks!

**EDIT:** This is the `originalRequest` in Retrofit 2:

```
Request{method=PUT, url=http://example.com/api/users/3/status?seId=0&dt=2016-10-04T05:30:00Z, tag=null}

headers: Authorization: Bearer LONG_TOKEN_HERE

contentType: application/json; charset=UTF-8

content:

0 = 123
1 = 34
2 = 115
3 = 116
4 = 97
5 = 116
6 = 117
7 = 115
8 = 34
9 = 58
10 = 51
11 = 125

Translated content:
{"status":3}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `token` you pass to `updateEventStatus` has the value: "Bearer " + LONG_TOKEN_HERE

Comment: Yea, I am using it in almost all of my methods.

Comment: Can you post the request made using retrofit?

Comment: @CliveSeebregts I added all the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, it was a server-side bug (I received a false seId at first, and then tried to PUT using an seId that doesn't exist).