# What is the reason of getting error 400 when you want to use retrofit lib in android studio?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, postman, http-status-code-400

In the following code I am trying to get 3 strings(username, password and email) from the user inside `RegisterFragment` and pass it to the server via `Retrofit` library inside android studio. But I get `Error 400`. I know it should work as it is one of our homework and the other guys did it successfully, but I don't know which part of my code is wrong!

I tried to debug the program and inside `RegisterController.java` within `onFailure` function it says:

`onFailure():= java.lang.illegalArgumentException: invalid argument count. expected 2 , received 0` .

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.m.chatroom;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.m.chatroom.Data.ChatRoomAPI;
import com.m.chatroom.Data.RegisterserController;
import com.m.chatroom.Models.User;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_main , registerFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();


    }

}
```

ChatRoomApi :

```
package com.m.chatroom.Data;


import com.m.chatroom.Models.User;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ChatRoomAPI {

    public static final String auth= "5a1d*******fabd";
    String BASE_URL = "https://api.backtory.com/";

    @Headers("X-Backtory-Authentication-Id:5a1d4b******fabd")
    @POST("auth/users")
    Call<User> registerUser(@Body User user);

    interface RegisterUserCallback
    {
        void onResponse(User user);
        void onFailure(String cause);
    }
}
```

RegisterController:

```
package com.m.chatroom.Data;


import android.util.Log;

import com.m.chatroom.Data.ChatRoomAPI;
import com.m.chatroom.Models.User;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RegisterserController {

    ChatRoomAPI.RegisterUserCallback registerUserCallback;

    public RegisterserController(ChatRoomAPI.RegisterUserCallback registerUserCallback) {
        this.registerUserCallback = registerUserCallback;
    }

    public void start(User user)
    {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ChatRoomAPI.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        ChatRoomAPI chatRoomAPI = retrofit.create(ChatRoomAPI.class);
        Call<User> call = chatRoomAPI.registerUser(user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                Log.wtf("TAG" , "onresposne  " + response.code() );
                registerUserCallback.onResponse(response.body());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.wtf("TAG" , "failure  " + t.getCause() );
                registerUserCallback.onFailure(t.getCause().getMessage());


            }
        });

    }
}
```

RegisterFragment:

```
package com.m.chatroom;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.m.chatroom.Data.ChatRoomAPI;
import com.m.chatroom.Data.RegisterserController;
import com.m.chatroom.Models.User;


public class RegisterFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

    private EditText userName;
    private EditText password;
    private EditText email;
    private Button registerButton;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        userName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
        password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
        email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
        registerButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_register);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RegisterserController registerserController = new RegisterserController(registerUserCallback);
                User user = new User();

                user.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
                user.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                user.setUserName(userName.getText().toString());
                registerserController.start(user);

            }
        });

    }
    ChatRoomAPI.RegisterUserCallback registerUserCallback = new ChatRoomAPI.RegisterUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(User user) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user.getUserName() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String cause) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cause , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    };
}
```

User.java:

```
package com.m.chatroom.Models;



public class User {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String serName) {
        this.userName = serName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public User() {


    }
}
```

Edit : Inside the postman software, I can send this query:

```
{
    "username":"xyzxyzxyz",
    "password":"xyzxyzxyz",
    "email":"xyzxyzxyz@gmail.com"
}
```

And get this result(code 201):

```
{
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "instanceId": "5a1d*****16474fabd",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "active": "true",
    "guest": "false",
    "avatar": null,
    "creationDate": "2018-02-09T06:35:04.561Z",
    "userId": "5a7d4118e4b02316b5e5fe09",
    "email": "xyzxyzxyz@gmail.com",
    "username": "xyzxyzxyz"
}
```

Comment: Error 400 is http error code (**400 Bad Request**), so your query is missing something. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082844/how-to-pass-string-in-body-parameter-of-retrofit-2-in-android) since it looks similar.

Comment: Sounds like the chat room API you are using is expecting 2 arguments for the function that url is bound to. Whether those are url parameters or query parameters, you'll have to determine based on the API.

Comment: First Clarify that , What should be JSON Request(Parameter expecting) needed for you 
e.g
Json Input data
{"userName": "test"}
Json response
{"success": true}.
look for the API and pass the needed parameter expecting for it

Comment: @seon: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's stupid, but I changed this line of code `private String userName;`
 to `private String username;`
 inside the `User.java` and it worked!

As you can see here

```
{
    "username":"xyzxyzxyz",
    "password":"xyzxyzxyz",
    "email":"xyzxyzxyz@gmail.com"
}
```

The API gets `username` not `userName` !