# How to pass a value to the retrofit url for a post request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to make a post request with retrofit to rate a movie with https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/rate-movie. The thing is, the url itself takes on the movie's id like this:

```
@POST("/movie/{id}/rating?api_key=${API_KEY}")
fun postRating(@Path("id") id:Int): Call<RatingResponse>
```

And then I need to also pass my rating value to make the post request. I did that through here (I think):

Remote data source:

```
interface RatingCallBack {
        fun onSuccess()
        fun onError(message: String?)
    }

    fun postRating(rating: Int, ratingCallback: RatingCallBack){
        val service = RetrofitService.instance
            .create(MovieService::class.java)

        val call = service.postRating(rating)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<RatingResponse?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<RatingResponse?>,
                response: Response<RatingResponse?>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("d","d")
                } else {
                    Log.d("d","d")
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RatingResponse?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("d","d")
            }
        })

    }
```

The viewmodel:

```
class RatingViewModel constructor(
   private val remoteDataSource: MovieRemoteDataSource
): ViewModel() {


   val ratingSuccess = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
   val ratingFailedMessage = MutableLiveData<String?>()

   fun postRating(rating:Int){
       remoteDataSource.postRating(rating, object: MovieRemoteDataSource.RatingCallBack{
           override fun onSuccess(){
               ratingSuccess.postValue(true)
           }
           override fun onError(message:String?){
               ratingSuccess.postValue(false)
               ratingFailedMessage.postValue(message)
           }
       })
   }
}
```

And in the fragment (I'll pass the user's rating later if this works):

```
binding.btRating.setOnClickListener {
   viewModel.postRating(2)
}
```

The thing is, I don't know where I'm supposed to pass the movie's id so that I can pass it to the url in retrofit since the movie's id is something I get through a bundle I send to my fragment from my activity like this:

```
val idInt = arguments?.getInt("Id")
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand API docs correctly, you need to use **Body** parameter. Check out this example: [How to pass string in 'Body' Parameter of Retrofit 2 in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082844/how-to-pass-string-in-body-parameter-of-retrofit-2-in-android)

Comment: Oh, I see.. wouldn't that be for the rating then? What about the movie's id?

Comment: @satoru Is number "2" in your code represents movie rating?

Comment: It does but it will be replaced later with the user's rating. And then there's the movie's id that goes in the url to post the rating to that movie

Comment: @satoru Well, then just change your method in ViewModel to `postRating(rating: Int, movieId: Int)` and call it from fragment like this: `arguments?.getInt("Id")?.let { viewModel.postRating(2, it) }`

Comment: okay but for that I'd need to pass the body first to the retrofit request, right? and then pass the body which would be 2 and then it which would be the path?

Comment: You would pass body and movie id together. I would do `@POST("/movie/{id}/rating?api_key=${API_KEY}")
fun postRating(@Path("id") id:Int, @Body body: Map<String, Int>): Call<RatingResponse>`. I don't think that order of arguments matters.

Comment: okay but if you pass map then it gives the error Type mismatch.
Required:
Map<String, Int>
Found:
Int

Comment: @satoru pass mapOf("value" to movieId) instead of passing movieId directly