# How to Pass Json Object as Body to Retrofit 2.0 without creating POJO

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to pass json object as body in retrofit. but creating pojo classes seems like mess. is it possible to send json object without creating pojo class?

Comment: You can use `HashMap`

Comment: BTW using POJO is much better.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 . but i have json object inside have another json object inside have json array means. if i create POJO for this , certainly getting confuse. thats why i asked question.

Comment: You should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request

Comment: @Rohit5k2 thanks . i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not replying directly the question but (for me) pojos are the way to go when you can generate them so easily and keep the project clean by using @AutoValue library.

- Import in your gradle app file

  ```
  provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
  apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
  apt 'com.github.rharter:auto-value-gson:0.2.5'
  ```
- Create object with autovalue:

  ```
  @AutoValue public abstract class MyObject {    
      @SerializedName("my_data") public abstract String myData();
      @SerializedName("some_extra_data") public abstract ExtraData extraData();

      public static TypeAdapter<MyObject> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
          return new AutoValue_MyObject.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
      }
  }

  @AutoValue public abstract class ExtraData {    
      @SerializedName("my_extra_data") public abstract String myExtraData();
      @SerializedName("my_extra_data2") public abstract String myExtraData2();

      public static TypeAdapter<ExtraData> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
          return new AutoValue_ExtraData.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
      }
  }
  ```
- Send it to with your Service

  ```
  @POST("somedata/data/")
  Call<Data> sendData (MyObject request);
  ```