# RetroFit interface method arguments

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am using RetroFit for the first time, so it is confusing me. I am trying to pass a JSON object to the server via POST. However I don't know how can make the model classes and the methods for the retrofit library. My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Header": {
    "UserDetails": "sample string 1",
    "ClientCode": "sample string 2",
    "Password": "sample string 3",
    "ViewType": 0,

  },
  "MemberDetails": {
    "Username": "sample string 1",
    "Password": "sample string 2",
    "MemberNo": "sample string 3",
    "MobileNo": "sample string 4"
  }
}
```

I have generate 2 model classes: `Header and MemberDetails`

The Interface class is like this:

```
public interface MyServerAPI {
    @POST("users/memberlogin")
    Call<> login(@Body WHAT_OBJECT_TO_PASS_HERE?);
}
```

I don't know whether to pass both Header and MemberDetails object or put them in a ArrayList and pass that to the login().

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21423093/2394266

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)

Comment: Just create another class that has Header and MemberDetails class inside.

Answer (score 0):

The Interface class can be like this

```
    public interface MyServerAPI {
      @FormUrlEncoded
      @POST("users/memberlogin")
        Call<MyResponse> login(@Field("my_object") String myObject);
    }
```

Then you can pass your object as a json string like this

```
String jsonString=new Gson().toJson(obj);
Call<MyResponse> myResponse = myGithubApi.login(jsonString);
```

Comment: @user2498079 try this

Comment: how can I see the json (converted from Models to JSON raw by GSON) being sent to the server?

Comment: try to echo "my_object" at the server side

Comment: I don't control the server side. Anyways, I have enabled debugging on android app and it shows that the complete JSON isn't being sent to the server. Most of the fields in the model classes are missing in the json that is being sent to the server