# What is the best way to parse data to JSON and send it to web

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have an offline app with lot of data. I need to convert the sqlite data to JSON and send it to web server.

**I would like to know what is the best way to do that?**

Comment: I would suggest using GSON library. Its by google and it is robust. Have a look at this link.  https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: "offline app" with Internet?

Comment: Thanks @RageshRamesh.

Comment: @KNeerajLal, app will be used on places without the internet and later, when it comes to the area with internet it will upload data to web.

Comment: @RubyDigger19 What have done so far?

Comment: I have just started!

Comment: @RubyDigger19 I will give you a general idea to do so. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use jackson or gson. 
Construct POJO object and use these libs to convert to json https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Should be straight to work on.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11634329)

Comment: thanks for reminding @SmokeDispenser

Answer (score 2):

You need a `BroadCastReciever` that triggers when you get internet connectivity. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app) SO thread for more info.

Make a `Service` class that makes a webservice call to your website. I recommend using retrofit or volley library to make the webservice call. [Here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is the official guide to using retrofit.

Then use jackson/gson to convert your objects to json. See @autobot_101's answer on how to do that.

Pass this json data as a parameter to your webservice call. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request) SO thread for more info.

Link only answers are not good but I think this should give you an idea of how to approach the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it somehow. This is my first android app

Comment: @RubyDigger19 Sure. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Jackson API. You have to define a pojo, some annotations, and within no time you will have it running. 
Google Jackson API tutorials. Also there are some xml/json to pojo free online converters.

Lemme know if Google doesn't help you and I can write something quick for you.

Comment: It would be good if you can?