# Json Object Request using Retrofit2

Tags: android, post, retrofit2, jsonobjectrequest

I am new in retrofit. I completed all setup.
I add this gradle in build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

My Interface is like this:

```
public interface ILoginInterface {
    String BASE_URL= "MY_BASE_URL/";

    @POST("MY/API")
    Call<LoginResponseEntity> startLogin(@Body JSONObject jsonObject);

    class Factory{
        private static ILoginInterface instance;

        public static ILoginInterface getInstance(){
            if(instance==null){
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                instance = retrofit.create(ILoginInterface.class);
            }

            return instance;
        }

    }
}
```

My Calling procedure is like this:

```
ILoginInterface.Factory.getInstance().startLogin(jsonObject).enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponseEntity>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponseEntity> call, retrofit2.Response<LoginResponseEntity> response) {
                    Log.d("MS",response.body().fullName);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponseEntity> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("MS",t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Here `jsonObject` is like this:

```
{"user_name":"sajedul Karim", "password":"123456"}
```

Here it seems everything is ok but i didn't getting proper response.
I found a solution. it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31658057/3073945) . Does anybody have proper solution like Volley **JsonObjectRequest**

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are importing

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;
```

you should use

```
    import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```

Then you will get it's value.

Comment: Is there a way to use JSONObject instead of JsonObject? addConverterFactory maybe?