# Post raw json in body retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want post json request like that

{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "testApi", "params": {
    "message": "abc"
}
, "id": 1}

I read posts:

[How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)

but i can'not found class TypedInput, TypedByteArray, TypedString in my retrofit2 package. Where is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To POST a body in `Retrofit`, you create an object that represents this body, a class that includes `String jsonrpc`, `String method`, etc. Then, pass this object to the method that you define in your service interface and has a param with `@Body` annotation.

Here is an example for POST body object:

```
public class PostBody{

   String jsonprc;
   String method;
   Param param;

   public PostBody(...){
        //IMPLEMENT THIS
   }

   ...

   class Param{
       //IMPLEMENT THIS
   }

}
```

Comment: how i can represents params json array (from my example) to class fields?

Comment: Create static inner classes for it if that object is not required anywhere except that body.

Answer (score 3):

**POST** data to the server require **backhend program** which is post your **data to the database** in the server.....

Retrofit Post require RESTAPI and POJO Class ....

API Interface

```
public interface Api {
    @POST("/upload/{new}.json")
    Call<User> setData(@Path("new") String s1, @Body User user);
}
```

Retrofit Object

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("here-your-url")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
                .build();
```

APi object

```
Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
```

Retrofit Call

```
Call<User> call = api.setData("mahesh", new User("mahesh", "delhi"));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            t1.setText("Success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("sam", "fail");
            t1.setText("fail");
        }
    });
```

POJO class //this class you create just put your json data into this [POJOConvertion](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

```
public class User {

    String name;
    String address;

    public User(String name, String address) {
        this.address = address;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

enjoy coding.

**If you want any practice for the Retrofit than please use this** [Retrofit + Firebase](http://sushildlh-retro-firebase.blogspot.in/)