# Null-pointer Exception, Retrofit?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

I am trying to get an id from URL but getting the null pointer exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.hex.encode.ID_Model$User.id' on a null object reference
>           at com.hex.encode.Home$3.onResponse(Home.java:99)

and this is the code I am using to get the id:

```
private void GetID() {
        Call<ID_Model> idcall = fetchdata.getIdService().getID(user_search);
        idcall.enqueue(new Callback<ID_Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ID_Model> call,@NonNull Response<ID_Model> response) {
                assert response.body() != null;
                String fetched_id =response.body().getUser().getId;//this is where the exception is poping
                GetData(fetched_id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ID_Model> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                //something//
            }
        });
    }
```

and below is the fetchdata class:

```
class fetchdata {
    private static UserFetchData userdatafetch = null;
    private static UserIDFetch fetchService = null;

    static  UserIDFetch getIdService() {
        if (fetchService == null) {
            String id_url = "url_and_it's_working";
            Retrofit fetch_id = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(id_url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            fetchService = fetch_id.create(UserIDFetch.class);
        }
        return fetchService;
    }

    public interface UserIDFetch{
        @GET("{user_input}"+"/")
        Call<ID_Model> getID(@Path("user_input") String s);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Here is the Id_Model :

```
public class ID_Model {

    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    public User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public class User {

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        public String id;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit**
Here is the response from the API Server :
https://justpaste.it/4gk8r

Comment: maybe use response.isSucessful()

Comment: `ID_Model` will be null if retrofit failed to parse the html body into your object. Show the raw url response and your model class, please

Comment: hii @cricket_007 i've posted the ID_MODEL class in the main question please take a look.

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa check i have used OnResponce callback so the response is successfull there is somethingin the ID_Model. I have update question with it.

Comment: Always you receive response, but, response code can be 200(OK), 400(BAD REQUEST)

Comment: Please show the html response as well for the url your application is reading from

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa the response is OK 200.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've posted the responce from the server in the main question please follow the link to view it. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You need to check response is successful with `response.isSucessful()`. And it also depends on server side they send the `200` when **API** successfully hit on server and then we need to check the **API** response is it `success` or `failure` on the basis of the response.

In your case, I think **API** call is success with `200` and return some response but `response.body().getUser()` is `null`. So you have to check the response of **API**.

Answer (score 2):

Your response looks like this

```
{
   ... 
  "graphql": {
     "user": {
       ... 
      "id": "1067259270",
```

Which means you have forgot to parse the `graphql` key as well as every other key, therefore the user is null.

At an absolute minimum you need a model like this.

```
class ResponseModel {
    GraphQLModel graphql;

    class GraphQLModel {
        UserModel user;

        class UserModel {
            int id;
        } 
    } 
}
```

[My suggestion would be to use an actual GraphQL library rather than Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43423565/2308683) and generate your model using apollo-codegen (if you use Apollo Client)

Comment: Yes just found that, how can i update the current ID_MODEL for this ?

Comment: I would use `apollo-codegen` project to create every GraphQL model for you rather than changing your model by hand