# Retrofit 500 Internal Server Error, Postman working

Tags: android, api, retrofit, postman

I know there must've been 1000 posts like this one, but I searched for the mistake everywhere and could not find it, so i hope you guys can take a look and tell me if you notice something i am missing.

**Token class**

```
public class Token {

public static final String POST = "tokens";

@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
private String token;
@SerializedName("role")
@Expose
private String role;

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
    }
}
```

**Entity class**

```
public class Entity {

public Entity(){}

private Token mToken;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String mEmail;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String mPassword;

public Entity setFirstName(String firstName){return this;}
public Entity setLastName(String lastName){return this;}
public Entity setEmail(String email){
    mEmail = email;
    return this;
}
public Entity setPassword(String password){
    mPassword = password;
    return this;
}
public Entity setPasswordConfirmation(String passwordConfirmation){return this;}
public Entity setAddress(String address){return this;}
public Entity setCity(String city){return this;}
public Entity setCountryId(Integer countryId){return this;}
public Entity setToken(Token token){
    mToken = token;
    return this;
}

public String getEmail(){ return mEmail; }
public String getPassword(){ return mPassword; }
public Token getToken(Token token){ return mToken; }
}
```

**APIService**

```
 @POST(Token.POST)
Observable<Token> loginEntity(@Body Entity entity);
```

**API call**

```
Observable<Token> loginEntityCall = RestClient.getInstance().service.loginEntity(loginEntity);
```

**What OkHttp outputs**

> --> POST http://randomapi/api/v1/tokens http/1.1
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Length: 55
>   {"email":"sample.user@example.com","password":"123456"}
>   --> END POST (55-byte body)

It returns

> <-- 500 Internal Server Error

**Here is the copied value into postman**

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SutlW.png)

So postman gives OK, and my app gives me 500. I checked all values and i cannot find the mistake. :p

Comment: Did you check the server logs?

Comment: @cricket_007 no, i don't have the server access at this moment

Comment: Well, that's the only thing that can give you the reason for the internal error. I'm guessing that retrofit isn't sending JSON, or you need to specify that as a header to the request

Comment: there are 3 headers in the postman screenshot. Make sure you use them.

Comment: Use a proxy to observe precisely your request.

Comment: I've removed the 3rd header, and it still works without it, so that seems not to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same thing happened to me. In Postman you are sending RAW json, but with Retrofit you are not doing that by default. Basically, you are not sending exactly the same thing. Change it to send raw json. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)