# how to pass raw json data to retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Hi i am new to retrofit and facing problem to post json data for calling api's. I tried with many solutions but not getting the answer.

This is my code

```
                      Map<String,String> data=new HashMap<>();
                data.put("email",email);
                data.put("feedback",feedback);
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), (new JSONObject(data)).toString());
                Call<Feedback> call = apiInterface.feedbackResponse(accessToken,tokenType,client,expiry,uid,body);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Feedback>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Feedback> call, Response<Feedback> response) {
                        Log.e("Response",String.valueOf(response.code()));
                        Message message=response.body().getMessage();
                        String messageBody=message.toString();
                        String status=response.body().getStatus();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),status+" : "+messageBody,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Feedback> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

and My interface is

```
      @POST("feedbacks")
public Call<Feedback> feedbackResponse(@Header(ApiConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN) String accessToken, @Header(ApiConstant.TOKEN_TYPE) String tokenType,
                                       @Header(ApiConstant.CLIENT) String client, @Header(ApiConstant.EXPIRY) String expiry,
                                       @Header(ApiConstant.UID) String uid, @Body RequestBody feedback);
```

Using headers like this is not giving problem as i am using it for every api. So dont consider headers is the problem.

My Response is

```
  public class Feedback {
private Message message;

private String status;

private Data data;

public Message getMessage ()
{
    return message;
}

public void setMessage (Message message)
{
    this.message = message;
}

public String getStatus ()
{
    return status;
}

public void setStatus (String status)
{
    this.status = status;
}

public Data getData ()
{
    return data;
}

public void setData (Data data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [message = "+message+", status = "+status+", data = "+data+"]";
}
```

}

Plese suggest me the right way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21398598/7012517 for ur reference..!

Comment: dude, i followed this tutorial also. but not getting the response. It is showing the Nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

Change signature to

```
@POST("feedbacks")
    public Call<Feedback> feedbackResponse(@Header(ApiConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN) String accessToken, @Header(ApiConstant.TOKEN_TYPE) String tokenType,
                                           @Header(ApiConstant.CLIENT) String client, @Header(ApiConstant.EXPIRY) String expiry,
                                           @Header(ApiConstant.UID) String uid, @Body Map<String,Object> feedback);
```

and calling to

```
Map<String,Object> data=new HashMap<>();
                data.put("email",email);
                data.put("feedback",feedback);
apiInterface.feedbackResponse(accessToken,tokenType,client,expiry,uid,data);
```

**or** change @Body data type to `JsonObject` and try

```
JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
    data.addProperty("email",email);
    data.add("feedback",new Gson().toJsonTree(feedback));
apiInterface.feedbackResponse(accessToken,tokenType,client,expiry,uid,data);
```

**or** you can also try `@Body FeedbackRequestData data`. there are multiple way to do it.

`apiInterface` must initialize with gson parser.
And if header is required in every request then use okHttp interceptor.

Make sure your Feedback class is generated by http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ while choosing JSON and GSON

Comment: Ya i tried this, getting this error.   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.androidapp.dooble.networks.Message com.androidapp.dooble.networks.Pojo.feedback.Feedback.getMessage()' on a null object reference

Comment: Try this JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
    data.addProperty("email",email);
    data.add("feedback",new Gson().toJsonTree(feedback));

Comment: same, no change