# How to post data using HashMap in retrofit?

Tags: android, post, get, gson, retrofit2

Can you please explain how to post data using **hashmap** in **retrofit2** ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what I post

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("getProfile")
Call<YourResponseObject> getProfile(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> data);
```

And the HashMap

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("token", "yourtoken");
        map.put("yourvariable", "yourvariable");
```

Comment: Can you please explain how total process go till i get the response using any other example !

Comment: @AkashRatanpara instead of sending parts of request, you can use HashMap, using HashMap can dynamically what params you want to send. The response of API will automatically parsing using GSON to `YourResponseObject`.

Comment: More useful details and examples, you can visit this site. I learned from this. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: If i don't want to make model then what is other way to call service?

Comment: @AkashRatanpara you can parse it to `String`. Not by using `GSON` use `Scalar` converter.

Answer (score 1):

From Retrofit2 documentation check FieldMap for more details
You need to create your interface

```
public interface YourPostService {  
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/myEndpoint")
    Call<YourResponseClass> postData(@FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
}
```

and after this is easy to call and use it