# How can i POST json data in Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

In my application I want **POST** some data, and this data get users and **POST** to server. For server requests I use **`Retrofit2`**.
For **POST** this data I should POST with **`json`** format, such as this :

```
{
  "email": "example@example.com",
  "username": "example",
  "password": "123",
}
```

After **POST** data I should check with this **results** for submit data has Ok ro Not.

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "Message": "",
  "data": true
}
```

I give Email, Username and Password with `EditText` from users, but how can I **POST** this data to server with **`Json`** format?

Please help me, I am amateur and I really need this help

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create a class for your request, for example, LoginRequest.java

```
public class LoginRequest {
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;

//getters and setters
}
```

Secondly, create a class for your response, LoginResponse.java

```
public class LoginResponse {
private Integer status;
private String Message;
private Boolean data;

//getters and setters
}
```

Finally, in your interface add this method:

```
public interface MiApiInterface {
    @POST("yourResourceName") Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest request);
}
```

I hope It could help you, just ask me if you have more question.

have you realised that the return of the login method is a Call, it is for a async call, you could use it like this on your activity:

firstly, create a retrofit instance

```
Retrofit retrofit = ....
```

Secondly, create your interface instance like this:

```
MiApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(MiApiInterface.class);
```

Finally, you could access the login method:

```
    LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest();
    request.set();
    ....

    Call<LoginResponse> responseCall = apiInterface.login(request);

    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
public void onResponse(...){
LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
}

public void onFailure(...){
}
    }
```

To Convert Objects to Json automatically, you should add a Converter Factory on your retrofit builder:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
...
```

dont forget import the Gson library on your gradle.

Comment: Thanks, I create this classes. how can on POST this data in MainActivity? how can I post this data in onResponse of retrofit?

Comment: Please help me my friend. I really need this. I am amateur :( please

Comment: I added more steps :D

Comment: thanks man, I know how can I use Retrofit and I create my classes. but my problem is how can I convert my data (email, username, password) to json and send this json file to server? how can I it?

Comment: Oh, import gson and create a Converter factory as I have added

Comment: can you send me your skype account? please

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on Retrofit 2: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Alternatively, you can use Volley, it is a library specificaly designed to make http requests on Android. https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: I want use retrofit. can you help me?

Comment: Document is very general, can you send me code my above data? please my friends, I really need this. please