# How do I get "nameValuePairs" in a JSON request using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

How do I post post a `JSONObject` request like below?

#### Original REQUEST:

```
    {
        "pObj": [],
        "robj": [
            {
                "l_index": "1",
                "user_id": "111",
                "vername": "1",
                "fcmtoken": "ghkghkhkh"
            }
        ],
        "uobject": [],
        "pname": "y6y68uuy7"
    }
```

In Volley I can successfully post `JSONObject` request. But when I am using this in Retrofit my request is changed as below:

#### What I am get in log:

```
  {
        "nameValuePairs": {
            "pObj": {
                "values": []
            },
            "robj": {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "nameValuePairs": {
                            "l_index": "1",
                            "user_id": "111",
                            "vername": "1",
                            "fcmtoken": "ghkghkhkh"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "uobject": {
                "values": []
            },
                    "pname": "y6y68uuy7"
        }
    }
```

And I am getting bad request from server side.

#### My API Interface for Retrofit:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @POST("re_clientdata")

    Call<String> savePost(@Body JSONObject  req);
}
```

#### My APIClient

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendPost(jRequest);
}

public void sendPost(JSONObject requestobject) {
    Log.e("requestobject",requestobject.toString());

    Call<String> call =mAPIService.savePost(requestobject);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String>callback,Response<String>response) {
            String res = response.body();
            Log.e("DEMO", "post submitted to API." + response);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("DEMO", "Unable to submit post to API.",t);
            Log.e("call", String.valueOf(call));
        }
    });

}
```

**Note:** I also tried using `HashMap` but same `nameValuePairs` parameter added automatically. And If I use Gson `JsonObject` then request convert in serialize. So I don't want to any change in server side cause it's works fine using Volley. But now I want to use Retrofit using same request.

Comment: Try this solution may it will help you out.
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/36821182/7750922](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36821182/7750922)

Comment: welcome mate @ a.dev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Change In your My APi Interface for Retrofit**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @POST("re_clientdata")


    Call<String> savePost(@Body RequestBody req);
}
```

**Also change Mainactivity code like this**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                
                 sendPost(jRequest);
    
        }

        public void sendPost(JSONObject requestobject) {
            Log.e("requestobject",requestobject.toString());
           
              RequestBody myreqbody = null;
                try {
                     myreqbody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),
                            (new JSONObject(String.valueOf(requestobject))).toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Call<String> call =mAPIService.savePost(myreqbody);


            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String>callback,Response<String>response) {
                    String res = response.body();
                    Log.e("DEMO", "post submitted to API." + response);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("DEMO", "Unable to submit post to API.",t);
                    Log.e("call", String.valueOf(call));
                }
            });

        }
```

> For more details check this
> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821182/6333971) suggested by
> **Pratik Vyas** .

---

---

### **In kotlin**

```
fun sendPost(requestobject: JSONObject) {
    Log.e("requestobject", requestobject.toString())
    var myreqbody: RequestBody? = null
    try {
        myreqbody = JSONObject(requestobject.toString()).toString()
            .toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    val call: Call<String> = mAPIService.savePost(myreqbody)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<String?>() {
        fun onResponse(callback: Call<String?>?, response: Response<String?>) {
            val res: String = response.body()
            Log.e("DEMO", "post submitted to API.$response")
        }

        fun onFailure(call: Call<String?>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("DEMO", "Unable to submit post to API.", t)
            Log.e("call", java.lang.String.valueOf(call))
        }
    })
}
```