# unable to send whole json as Body param in api retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am referring this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request/21423093#21423093) but unable to generate proper api request. api request is as below

**Request :**

```
{
  "clientId": "v@gmail.com",
  "products": {
    "productNumber": "8123456789123",
    "batchNumber": "123456789",
    "quantity": 50,
    "salesPrice": 500,
    "purchasePrice": 500,
    "MRP": 600,
    "mfgDate": "15/05/2017",
    "expDate": "15/05/2017"
  }
}
```

**Api Interface**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/products/addBatch")
public Observable<AddBatchResponse> doAddBatch(@Header(WebServicesTags.TAG_AUTHORIZATION) String token,
                                               @Field(WebServicesTags.TAG_CLIENT_ID) String clientId,
                                               @Body BatchModel product);
```

and following is my **Api call**

```
BatchModel model = new BatchModel(productNumber, batchNumber, quantity, salesPrice, purchasePrice, mRP, mfgDate, expDate);
Observable<AddBatchResponse> addBatch = apiservice.doAddBatch(sessionManager.getKeyToken(), sessionManager.getKeyEmail(), model);
        addBatch.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
```

call this api shows me below **Error**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used
>   with form or multi-part encoding.

Comment: remove @FormUrlEncoded from Api Interface

Comment: then it is showing @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding.

Comment: then add clientId in  JSON model class, and use @HEADER for sending header value. so finally your interface looks like:  public Observable<AddBatchResponse> doAddBatch(@Body BatchModel product);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use @Field with @FormUrlEncoded or @Body.. you cant use both at a same time

Do something like

```
@POST("/products/addBatch")
public Observable<AddBatchResponse> doAddBatch(@Header(WebServicesTags.TAG_AUTHORIZATION) String token,
                                           @Body HashMap<String, Object> map);
```

and while posting data create a map

```
HashMap<String,Object> map  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("clientId","v@gmail.com");
map.put("product", batchModel);
```

Pass this map as the body parameter to the api call I hope this will solve your problem