# Retrofit,Android,How to RequestOrderStatusBean object(Retrofit @Body parameter) with RequestOrderStatusBean object

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

#### Retrofit request API format(Android):

```
 @POST("getOrderStatus")
 @Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
 Observable<Response> getOrderInfo(@Query("timeStamp") long ts, @Body RequestOrderStatusBean bean);
```

#### BuildRequestOrderStatusBean.java

```
 public class BuildRequestOrderStatusBean {
        public int startNum;
        public int endNum;
    }
```

#### RequestOrderStatusBean.java

RequestOrderStatusBean is **@Body parameter** in Retrofit API **getOrderInfo**.

RequestOrderStatusBean object will be built with many same data structure but different var name BuildRequestOrderStatusBean object.

```
 public class RequestOrderStatusBean {
    // TODO: How to use BuildRequestOrderStatusBean to build RequestOrderStatusBean object?
     /**
      {
        "arrayA" : { "startNum" : 10,  "endNum" : 50  },
        "arrayB" : { "startNum" : 100, "endNum" : 200 },
        "arrayC" : { "startNum" : 230, "endNum" : 300}
        ...
     */
    }
```

#### QA: How to build RequestOrderStatusBean object(Retrofit @Body parameter) with BuildRequestOrderStatusBean object?

## Ref:

- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0
- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0
- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0
- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4

Comment: Have you found any solution on that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create model class with dynamic keys instead you can use **JsonObject** to achieve the same (see carefully its **JsonObject** not JSONObject)

```
JsonObject arrayA = new JsonObject();
arrayA.addProperty("startNum", 10);
arrayA.addProperty("endNum", 50);

JsonObject arrayB = new JsonObject();
arrayB.addProperty("startNum", 100);
arrayB.addProperty("endNum", 200);

JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.add("arrayA", arrayA);
object.add("arrayB", arrayB);
```

its output is

```
{
   "arrayA":{
            "startNum":10,"endNum":50
   },
   "arrayB":{
            "startNum":100,"endNum":200
   }
}
```

this is just an example you can add as many object as you want using for loop etc.

Then in retrofit change you interface method to **@Body JsonObject bean**

```
 @POST("getOrderStatus")
 @Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
 Observable<Response> getOrderInfo(@Query("timeStamp") long ts, @Body JsonObject bean);
```

retrofit will handle it like any other model class.

Comment: Thank you very much .        If ``@Body`` bean is very simple,we can use the ``JsonObject``. But if is complicated， we can not use ``JsonObject``, because building  the ``@Body`` bean is very time consuming and  not flexible.

Comment: @ Nishant Pardamwar, I have found the solution by using ``TypedInput``  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request>