# How to put JSON array in request body for Retrofit?

Tags: java, json, retrofit2, http-patch

The server API takes a JSON array in the request body. Like this:

```
[
  {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3"
  }
]
```

I know how to put a JSON object as the body, but how can I put a JSON **array** in a retrofit request?

I already have a POJO:

```
public class Sample {
    @SerializedName("key1")
    @Expose
    private String key1;
    @SerializedName("key2")
    @Expose
    private String key2;
    @SerializedName("key3")
    @Expose
    private String key3;
}
```

Here's my API class:

```
  @PATCH("//some url")
    Observable<ResponseBody> patchRequest(
            // ... other params
            @Body Sample sampleBody;
    );
```

When I make a request, the body looks like this:

```
  {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3"
  }
```

Except I need it to be inside an array as show in the first JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)

Comment: Please show a code example that illustrates what you tried so far.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is there a more elegant way instead of posting a raw JSON body?

Answer (score 0):

Use list of that objects

```
@POST("url")
Call<Object> doStuff(@Body List<Map<String, String>> body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a list of `Sample`s. It will then wrapped into a JSON array.

```
@PATCH("//some url")
Observable<ResponseBody> patchRequest(
        // ... other params
        @Body List<Sample> sampleBody;
);
```