# sending a JSONArray containing only a string in retrofit

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, retrofit

so I am trying to make a server request and the expected body for this request looks like this: `["1"]`

but if I send a string as `"[\"1\"]"`, I am getting an error

looking at the body, it's clear that I have to send a `JSONArray` ,  I tried achieving this using the following code:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("1");
```

but my body on stetho is shown as :

```
{
    "values":["1"]
}
```

maybe I am using a wrong class or something !

EDIT:

This is my api call with

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
                    .build();

RetrofitService retrofitService2 =new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://blynk-cloud.com/")
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                    .create(RetrofitService.class);

retrofitService2.closeDoor("3bf11f14e6094dd5a8f31f6d6fac8f3d",
                    "[\"1\"]")
                    .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                           {

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
```

closeDoor method:

```
@PUT("/{id}/update/D12")
    Call<String> closeDoor(@Path("id") String id, @Body String code);
```

my stetho response :
[image]

Comment: `["1"]` is not a properly formatted JSON string.  If that is what you have to send, you are not going to be able to get it from any of the Android JSON classes; you'll need to just construct the string yourself and send it.

Comment: i was sending ["1"] as a string using "[\"1\"]" 
but it was still giving me the same issue

Comment: Can you update your post to include the code you are using to create the HTTP request and send it?  Are you using the native HttpURLConnection class, or a HTTP library?

Comment: using retrofit here i am getting server error code 500 and everything seems to be fine except for maybe the body,
are you sure this is the way?

Comment: Post your `RetrofitService` interface, at least the `closeDoor` method. There might be some clues there.

Comment: i have edited the question please check!

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari API working in postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send request JSON like this  `["1"]`

Change to :

```
    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
    array.add(new JsonPrimitive("1"));
    //output ["1"]
```

Instead of:

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a `500` error is that you are sending the response as `text\plain` as supposed to `application\json` which the server is expecting.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request#comment61118550_21423093), to send a raw JSON you need to use a `RequestBody` and pass it instead of `String`

```
RequestBody body = new RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),"[\"1\"]");

retrofitService2.closeDoor("3bf11f14e6094dd5a8f31f6d6fac8f3d",body).enqueue(...)
```

And change your retrofit method to

```
@PUT("/{id}/update/D12")
Call<String> closeDoor(@Path("id") String id, @Body RequestBody body);
```