# Registration in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

```
 public void onResponse(Call<RegisterModel> call, Response<RegisterModel> response) {

                if(response.body().getSuccess()==1){

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                    if(response.body().getSuccess()==0){

                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Entered Email already exit ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisterModel> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
```

cursor automatically come out failure block...

Comment: Check the failure thrown on log and it would be better for people if you post the log in your question.

Answer (score 0):

please print your response log code like this and use `if (response.isSuccessful())` to know response is success or not

```
Call<ResponseBean> registerCall = ApiHandler.getApiService().ApiName(ApiJsonMap());
        registerCall.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBean>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBean> registerCall, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBean> response) {

                try {
                    //print respone
                    Log.e(" Full json gson => ", new Gson().toJson(response));
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response).toString());
                    Log.e(" responce => ", jsonObj.getJSONObject("body").toString());

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        int success = response.body().getSuccess();
                        if (success == 1) {



                        } else if (success == 0) {



                        }  
                    } else {
                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        Log.e("Tag", "error=" + e.toString());

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBean> call, Throwable t) {
                try {
                    Log.e("Tag", "error" + t.toString());

                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

for more [help follow my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request) step by step implementation