# How to parse Nested json using Retrofit ....?

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

I don't know how to **parse json using retrofit**. Am familiar with parsing simple json using Retrofit but am not familiar with parsing **nested Json** using **Retrofit**.

Here is my  Json data.................

```
  {
         "current_observation": {
             "image": {
                 "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",                
                 "title":"Weather Underground",
                 "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
},
                  {
                  "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",               
                 "title":"Weather Underground",
                 "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
                   }
             }
         }
     }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

This is my method for simple json

```
public class Country {
    @SerializedName("current_observation")
    @Expose
    private List<Items> items;

    public List<Items> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems (List<Items> items) {
       this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Here comes.....

```
 public class Items {
        @SerializedName("image")
        @Expose
        private String url;
        private String title;
        private String link;

        public String getFlag() {
            return url;
        }
        public String getRank() {
           return link;
        }
        public void setRank(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }
        public void setFlag(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        public String getCountryname() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setCountryname(String rating) {
            this.title = rating;
        }
    }
```

Code in Main Activity

```
Call <Country>  call = apiInterface.getCountries();

        call.enqueue(new Callback <Country>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Country> call, Response<Country>  response) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onSuccess Server Response "+ response.toString());

                Log.d(TAG,"onSuccess received information "+ response.body().toString());
                List<Items> items = response.body().getItems();
                adapter = new RecAdapter(items, getContext().getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
```

Comment: you don't need to parse JSON object, use annotation in model class

Comment: show us how do you do with your "simple json", then we will suggest how to modify

Comment: yeah i ll show it. @Jacky

Comment: @farhana yeah i knew it. my code for simple json ll show more light

Comment: @Jacky kindly go thru my code

Comment: @farhana u too buddy....

Comment: you don't need to parse in retrofit, It will return you a list

Comment: Am sorry @farhana i cant catch your point

Comment: can you tell why you want to parse if retrofit parses data itself?

Comment: did you get solution with my way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CurrentObservation.class

```
public class CurrentObservation {

@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private Image1 image;

public Image1 getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(Image1 image) {
this.image = image;
}
}
```

Example.java

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("current_observation")
@Expose
private CurrentObservation currentObservation;

public CurrentObservation getCurrentObservation() {
return currentObservation;
}

public void setCurrentObservation(CurrentObservation currentObservation) {
this.currentObservation = currentObservation;
}
}
```

Image1.java

```
public class Image1 {

@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

}
```

To call it in main Activity

```
  Call<Example> ex = BaseUrlClass.getInterface().ex("whatever parameters");
    ex.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            Example list = response.body();

            CurrentObservation a = list.getCurrentObservation();
            List<Image1> im = a.getImage();
            for (int i = 0;i<im.size();i++){
                Image1 image1= im.get(i);
                String a = image1.getTitle();
                String b = image1.getUrl();
                String c = image1.getLink();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Lastly in your Interface

```
public interface ApiUtils {

@GET("")  //whatever url
Call<Example> ex();  //or any parameter
}
```

Comment: whats the error its giving. have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 4):

Use below `Response` class in `Retrofit`

```
class Response{
   @SerializedName("current_observation")
   Observation observation;
   //getters and setters
}

class Observation{
   @SerializedName("image")
   Image image;
   //getters and setters
}

class Image{
  @SerializedName("title")
  String title;
  @SerializedName("link")
  String link;
  @SerializedName("url")
  String url;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks bro ......how can i call it in main activity......??would you show me some sample.

Comment: @MilkaMozhi Here is the sample link http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/. Hope it helps

Comment: Post your entire Json , is that an object or array ?

Comment: wait bro i ll try

Comment: i have posted my entire json bro

Answer (score 2):

This will be easier if you implement the Pojo correctly.

There are a conflict in your class and your json.

From your Country class, "current_observation" will be `List<Items> items;`

Then your json should be like this:

```
"current_observation":[
{
     "image": {
         "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
         "title":"Weather Underground",
         "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
     }
},
{
     "image": {
         "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
         "title":"Weather Underground",
         "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
     }
}]
```

Take note at the square bracket `[]` in case of using List. Even if only 1 item, your `"current_observation"` still need to have this to declare for `List<T>`.

I suggest you use this website: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Choose `Source Type: JSON`, `Annotation style: Moshi` (I'm using Moshi, or you can use Gson), Tick on: `Make class serialiable`

It will generate the correct Class for your json. The rest of your code should be correct already.

**UPDATE**:
If after generating the class, there is no List generated, you should not use

```
List<Items> items = response.body().getItems();
```

but instead

```
Items items = response.body().getItems();
```

Comment: yeah your correct bro......Its list...not a single one.I trimmed it up to simplify the question...I have updated it now .Kindly go through it

Comment: @MilkaMozhi it's still wrong my friend, use a json validator and you can see it. That's why i suspected your json can't be serialize to your class

Answer (score 1):

For JSON Parsing you should use [JASONSCHEMA2POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) convert JSON String to model class

**inside your retrofit success response**

```
 CurrentObservation observation = new CurrentObservation  ();
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
 observation = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.getString("current_observation"),CurrentObservation .class);
```

**Model Class Like**

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("current_observation")
@Expose
private CurrentObservation currentObservation;

public CurrentObservation getCurrentObservation() {
return currentObservation;
}

 public void setCurrentObservation(CurrentObservation currentObservation) {
 this.currentObservation = currentObservation;
 }

}
```

Comment: @MilkaMozhi What is complex in the answer?

Comment: sry bro i was replied before seeing your edited post

Answer (score 1):

How can i call it in main activity?

you need to call pojo class method like this

```
String url=getCurrentObservation().getImage().getUrl();
```

if you get from response

```
String url=response.body().getCurrentObservation().getImage().getUrl();
```

for more help retrofit follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request) with my ans

Answer (score 0):

i looked at your Json String in detail. just look at your "image" key followed by a JSONObject.

```
{
     "current_observation": {
       "image": {
             "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",                
             "title":"Weather Underground",
             "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
},
              {
              "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",               
             "title":"Weather Underground",
             "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
               }

     }
 }
```

since your "image" key has multiple values, it should be inside the JSONArray. so your String should look like

```
{
     "current_observation": {
       "image": [{
             "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",                
             "title":"Weather Underground",
             "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
  },
              {
              "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",               
             "title":"Weather Underground",
             "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
               }
         ]

     }
 }
```

I suggest you should check your String again.