# Android When updating Retrofit 2.9.1 and okhttp 3.X.X the json Converter library showing errors

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, okhttp

Android When updating Retrofit 2.9.1  and okhttp 3.X.X the json Converter library showing errors compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13',

the all errors are same not found the all functions and arguments of json converter library of my app how can solve it with newest version of the Retrofit and okhttp library.

> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
>       compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
>       compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'

Comment: latest retrofit version is 2.4.0 why you use 2.9.1?
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @AD10 its not working for me

Comment: follow this =https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request