# JSON Data is not converting to JSONObject from StringRequest volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnIte
 @Override                                          
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, V
     if (position == 0) {                           

         title.clear();                             
         news_id.clear();                           
         date.clear();                              
         description.clear();                       
         img_url.clear();                           
         source_url.clear();                        
         category_to_fetch = "analysis";            
         getO(category_to_fetch);                   
     } else if (position == 1) {                    
         title.clear();                             
         news_id.clear();                           
         date.clear();                              
         description.clear();                       
         img_url.clear();                           
         source_url.clear();                        
         category_to_fetch = "blockchain";          
         getO(category_to_fetch);                   
     } else if (position == 2) {                    

         title.clear();                             
         news_id.clear();                           
         date.clear();                              
         description.clear();                       
         img_url.clear();                           
         source_url.clear();                        
         category_to_fetch = "exchanges";           
         getO(category_to_fetch);                   
     } else if (position == 3) {                    
         title.clear();                             
         news_id.clear();                           
         date.clear();                              
         description.clear();                       
         img_url.clear();                           
         source_url.clear();                        
         category_to_fetch = "general";             
         getO(category_to_fetch);                   
     } else if (position == 4) {                    

         title.clear();                             
         news_id.clear();                           
         date.clear();                              
         description.clear();                       
         img_url.clear();                           
         source_url.clear();                        
         category_to_fetch = "government";          
         getO(category_to_fetch);                   
     } else if (position == 5) {                    

         title.clear();                             
         news_id.clear();                           
         date.clear();                              
         description.clear();                       
         img_url.clear();                           
         source_url.clear();                        
         category_to_fetch = "ico";                 
         getO(category_to_fetch);                   
     } else if (position == 6) {                    

         title.clear();                             
         news_id.clear();                           
         date.clear();                              
         description.clear();                       
         img_url.clear();                           
         source_url.clear();                        
         category_to_fetch = "mining";              
         getO(category_to_fetch);                   
     }                                              


 }                                                  

 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(               
         Request.Method.GET,                                    
         Utils.CATEGORY, new Response.Listener<String>() {      
     @Override                                                  
     public void onResponse(String response) {                  
         try {                                                  
             Log.e("RESPONSE", response);                       

             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);  

             Log.e("OBJECT", jsonObject.toString());
```

*LOGCAT*

**THIS IS THE STRING RESPONSE**

E/RESPONSE: {"analysis":[// RESPONSE

**AFTER CONVERTING IT TO JSONOBJECT IT IS SHOWING DATA LIKE BELOW**
E/OBJECT: {"exchanges" :[// RESPONSE

WHEN I CHOOSE ANALYSIS CATEGORY FROM SPINNER DATA IS LOADED

WHEN I CHOOSE ANALYSIS CATEGORY FROM SPINNER DATA IS ICO

WHEN I CHOOSE ANALYSIS CATEGORY FROM SPINNER DATA IS MINING

else

DATA IS NOT LOADED EVEN THOUGH I HAVE THE DATA

Comment: what is the problem? also DON"T EXPOSE YOUR PRIVATE KEY!!

Comment: Okay @BasilBattikhi EDITED

Comment: where is your problem man, please be more specific, also , a full sample response would be helpful

Comment: I am fetching data according to JSONArray which I am getting from response but When I convert StringRequest response to JSONOBject like above data is not same ,I mean you can see above logcat .How can I convert it to JSONOBJECT like I am getting from StringResponse

Comment: Still not clear, the json object is just a string, what is the problem ?

Comment: I already told you, the JSON is not supposed to stay the same, because JSON properties don't have an order. It doesn't matter that it changed. All the data are still there and the same, just displayed not in the same order.

Comment: Is it too hard to give us a full sample response ?

Answer (score 0):

JSON properties are not ordered. It shouldn't bother you if they're suddenly displayed in a different order before and after parsing.

Comment: But I have to fetch data according to the JSONObject ..this is not working

Comment: @XayProgramming this is not a contest to use as few words as possible. Be specific. Show the JSON you have at various stages, with at least a bunch of lines and not just one word. Preferably show what you're interested in this JSON. Then show the code you have to try and make use of this JSON. Then explain what you obtain and what you wanted to obtain instead.

Comment: I have explained the issue in detail please see my question

Comment: @XayProgramming there are zero details in your question. I have told you the kind of details you need to give. First give them, then we'll see if you get to claim you gave details.

Comment: EDITED QUESTION SEE ABOVE

Comment: @XayProgramming You're still not showing the JSON in full, you're showing the first word and nothing else. Why? You're still not showing what you're doing with the JSON. I told you to. We don't know of a spinner. You could have made it all clearer. And caps are useless.

Answer (score 0):

if you use retrofit use `HttpLogginInterceptor` this interceptor which logs request and response information:
add gradle :

> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'

and add `.addInterceptor(interceptor)`

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
                .build();
```

and if you want to print response use GSON converter :

```
//print respone
Log.e(" Full json gson => ", new Gson().toJson(response));

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response).toString());
                        Log.e(" responce => ", jsonObj.getJSONObject("body").toString());
```

[check my ans here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request/36821182)