# I'm sending JSONObject code=500, message=Internal Server Error

Tags: android, rest, mobile, retrofit, retrofit2

**I'm posting multiple JSON arrays to but it gives an error internal server error but it's working fine on postman**

**Interface**

```
 @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Basic c3ltby1hcHAtaW9zOmE4ODI4NjY1LTU1MzgtNGNlYy1hYzU4LWE0YmU0NmE1Y2Y3OA==",
            "client-id: bitmoon-app-android"
    })
    @POST("medical-ic10/public/api/user/pending")
        Call<JSONObject>  SUBMIT_OFFLINE_RECORD(@Body JSONObject offlineRequest);
```

**implementation**

```
 public void getData(JSONObject J) {

        Api api= RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(Api.class);
        Call<JSONObject> call=api.SUBMIT_OFFLINE_RECORD(J);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Offlinerecord_Activity.this, ""+t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("GSON",t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**JSON OBJECT**

```
{"data":[{"id":"15","pName":"15","pAge":"15","pGender":"15","pPhone":"15","pNIC":"15","pDiagnosis":"15","dName":"15","dSpeciality":"15","dPhone":"15","dInstitution":"15","dAssistantName":"15","dCity":"15"}]}
```

**Postman Screen**

[image]

Comment: Share your postman screen please

Comment: Do you need send api key? Cookies?

Comment: Nope just parameters. Method type, request and response etc. Dont forget to hide url link also.

Comment: Also evaluate the J parameted passed to getData method. It might be same as you do in postman.

Comment: check again @JuanjoBerenguer

Comment: Updated @EmreAktürk

Comment: i get all the that stroed in J and send that data to postman its working fine @EmreAktürk

Comment: show headers you have send by postMan

Comment: If you are just about J parameter, we might check headers.

Comment: Hello Shams. Take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request Maybe you need add applicaton/json in the headers

Comment: obviously because of using `JSONObject` instead POJO class

Comment: same as postman , i already checked it  @AniruddhParihar

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `JsonObject` class from Gson library in your API interface. (You don't need to include Gson library separately as you're using Retrofit) Like below

```
Call<JsonObject>  SUBMIT_OFFLINE_RECORD(@Body JsonObject offlineRequest);
```

If the above solution doesn't work create POJO classes and pass it as a parameter to `@Body` annotation.

User.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("pName")
    @Expose
    private String pName;
    @SerializedName("pAge")
    @Expose
    private String pAge;
    @SerializedName("pGender")
    @Expose
    private String pGender;
    @SerializedName("pPhone")
    @Expose
    private String pPhone;
    @SerializedName("pNIC")
    @Expose
    private String pNIC;
    @SerializedName("pDiagnosis")
    @Expose
    private String pDiagnosis;
    @SerializedName("dName")
    @Expose
    private String dName;
    @SerializedName("dSpeciality")
    @Expose
    private String dSpeciality;
    @SerializedName("dPhone")
    @Expose
    private String dPhone;
    @SerializedName("dInstitution")
    @Expose
    private String dInstitution;
    @SerializedName("dAssistantName")
    @Expose
    private String dAssistantName;
    @SerializedName("dCity")
    @Expose
    private String dCity;

    public User(String id, String pName, String pAge, String pGender, String pPhone, String pNIC, String pDiagnosis, String dName, String dSpeciality, String dPhone, String dInstitution, String dAssistantName, String dCity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pName = pName;
        this.pAge = pAge;
        this.pGender = pGender;
        this.pPhone = pPhone;
        this.pNIC = pNIC;
        this.pDiagnosis = pDiagnosis;
        this.dName = dName;
        this.dSpeciality = dSpeciality;
        this.dPhone = dPhone;
        this.dInstitution = dInstitution;
        this.dAssistantName = dAssistantName;
        this.dCity = dCity;
    }

    // other constructors, getter and setter methods

}
```

Data.java

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;

    public Example(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And change `@Body` annotation parameter from `JSONObject` to `Data` like below

```
Call<JsonObject>  SUBMIT_OFFLINE_RECORD(@Body Data offlineRequest);
```

Usage of POJO classes

```
User user = new User(/* pass all required parameters to constructor */);
Data data = new Data(user);  // pass User object to constructor 

// pass Data object to API request method
Api api= RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(Api.class);
Call<JsonObject> call = api.SUBMIT_OFFLINE_RECORD(data);  
// implement call listeners
```

Notice clearly I changed parameters from `JSONObject` to `JsonObject` as well in `Call<>` parameter.