# Retrofit/Spring Parsing Data Class to JSON Object

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I have the following data class:

```
data class Thing(
    val id: Long?,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
)
```

In my Api :

```
@POST("doThings")
    fun createThings(
        @Query("thing") thing: Thing
    ): Call<StatusResponse>
```

I got the error:
status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Unexpected character ('E' (code 69))

In the spring api I made a log output and the data class object arrived as:

"Thing(id=null, title=Something, description=Something more)"

The Retrofit Builder has the GSON Converter but I guess it doesn't work properly:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(get())
            .baseUrl(get<Context>().getString(R.string.base_url))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(get<CoroutineCallAdapterFactory>())
            .addConverterFactory(get<GsonConverterFactory>())
            .build()
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: How `JSON` payload which you send to `API` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `@Query` annotation which means your `Thing` will be serialised as a `String` and passed as a query parameter in the URL.

You instead want to use the `@Body` annotation which will serialise the `Thing` object as JSON and add it to the POST body.

This answer will give you more details on how to use that annotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423093/5577048