# JSON parse error: syntax error, expect {, actual error, pos 0, fastjson-version 1.2.57 when using RoyalPay SDK

Tags: kotlin, fastjson

I am trying to use RoyalPay SDK to create order and make Alipay payment. The response code is 200, but I cannot parse JSON in response.

How do I solve this problem?

The code I create api request with:

```
    interface RoyalPayApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers("Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/json")
    @PUT("/api/v1.0/gateway/partners/{partner_code}/app_orders/{order_id}")
    fun createRoyalPaySDKOrder(@Path(value = "partner_code", encoded = true) partner_code: String, @Path(value = "order_id", encoded = true) order_id: String,
                               @Query("time") time: Long, @Query("nonce_str") nonce_str: String, @Query("sign") sign: String,
                               @Field("description") description: String,
                               @Field("price") price: Int,
                               @Field("currency") currency: String,
                               @Field("channel") channel: String,
                               @Field("operator") operator: String,
                               @Field("system") system: String): Call<JSONObject> // com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject
}
```

The code I get retrofit service:

```
fun createService(): RoyalPayApi {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(ROYAL_PAY_ADDRESS)
        .addConverterFactory(FastJsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()

    return retrofit.create(RoyalPayApi::class.java)
}
```

The code I send request and receive response:

```
 var api = createService()
    var call = api.createRoyalPaySDKOrder(ROYAL_PAY_PARTNER_CODE, order_id, time, ROYAL_PAY_NONCE_STR, sign,
        description, price, "AUD", channel, "kate", "android")

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<JSONObject>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<JSONObject>, response: Response<JSONObject>) {
            val str = ""
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JSONObject>, t: Throwable) {
            val str = ""
        }
    })
```

This is the response I received:

[image]

This is the response body (Chinese here should not affect understanding):

[image]

This includes raw response (using com.google.gson.JsonObject):

[image]

Raw response using com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject
[image]

if change JSONObject to String, it just return the String version of error :(:
[image]

Comment: Please include response json body

Comment: @awesoon added, thanks

Comment: The keys in the table do not match keys in the `response.body` on the screenshot. Anyway I asked about actual json you have received, not a table. Please include actual json.

Comment: @awesoon i cannot received any json, it always report the error shown as the image above, or empty json if using com.google.gson.JsonObject

Comment: You received something (maybe this is valid json, maybe not), inspect the response object and include response raw body.

Comment: @awesoon I included raw response... the response body is empty if using com.google.gson.JsonObject, and raw response told me code is 200 but nothing...

Comment: The last screenshot does not produce error you've mentioned in the question (compare `response.body` - on the first screenshot it contains 4 elements, on the second it is empty). Make sure your request fails with JSON parse error and include raw response for that request.

Comment: @awesoon raw responses are actually same, no matter which JSONObject type used.... The difference is json parse error or empty json

Comment: You're right, I was confused by `return_code` and `timestamp`

Comment: Can you change the Retrofit API to request a String instead of a JSONObject? Then show us the string you received from the server.

Comment: @JensV changed and posted the response....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is expecting a JSON Body request. You are annotating your data with `@Field` which will result in the request formed as a queryString.

I.e. your request body will look something like this:

```
description=foo&price=123...
```

instead of this:

```
{
    "description": "foo",
    "price": 123,
    ...
}
```

To achieve what you want, check [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request). The first answer works directly with Java objects, but you can also use the second answer if you don't want to work with custom classes.