# How do I add a JSON body to my post request using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit

I am trying to send a POST request using Retrofit library.

Here is my `MarketApiCalls` interface and my networking method doing the work -

```java
public interface MarketApiCalls {


    @POST("api/Search/Vendor/Multiple")
    Call<String> getVendors(
            @Query("take") int take,
            @Query("page") int page,
            @Body String json
    );
}
```

```java
private void initNetworking() {
        String body = "[{ \"filters\": { \"VendorName\": { \"value\": [\"*\"], \"cretiria\": 0, \"type\": 5 } } }]"
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://search.myverte.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        marketApiCalls = retrofit.create(MarketApiCalls.class);

        Call<String> vendorsCall = marketApiCalls.getVendors(9, 0, body);
        vendorsCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Log.d("response body", response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the JSON I need to attach to the POST request as a body -

```
[{
    "filters": {
        "VendorName": { 
            "value": ["*"],
            "cretiria": 0,
            "type": 5
        }
    }
}]
```

The issue is that I am getting error code 400. It does not specify that the body is missing or corrupt , just gives 400 error saying the following error -

[image]

What am I missing? I am suspicious that I am not giving the body as needed.

edit -

I have tried the following solution yet the same error occurs -

```java
public class VendorBodyModel {
    private Filters filters;

    public VendorBodyModel() {
    }

    public VendorBodyModel(Filters filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    public Filters getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(Filters filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }
    public class Filters {
        private VendorName vendorName;

        public Filters() {
        }

        public Filters(VendorName vendorName) {
            this.vendorName = vendorName;
        }
    }

    public class VendorName {
        private String[] value;
        private int cretiria;
        private int type;

        public VendorName(String[] value, int cretiria, int type) {
            this.value = value;
            this.cretiria = cretiria;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String[] getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String[] value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getCretiria() {
            return cretiria;
        }

        public void setCretiria(int cretiria) {
            this.cretiria = cretiria;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public interface MarketApiCalls {


    @POST("api/Search/Vendor/Multiple")
    Call<String> getVendors(
            @Query("take") int take,
            @Query("page") int page,
            @Body VendorBodyModel bodyModel
    );
}
```

```java
private void initNetworking() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://search.myverte.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        marketApiCalls = retrofit.create(MarketApiCalls.class);
        String[] array = {"*"};
        int cretiria = 5;
        int type = 0;
        VendorBodyModel.VendorName vendorName = new VendorBodyModel().new VendorName(array, 5, 0);
        VendorBodyModel.Filters filters = new VendorBodyModel().new Filters(vendorName);
        VendorBodyModel vendorBodyModel = new VendorBodyModel(filters);

        Call<String> vendorsCall = marketApiCalls.getVendors(9, 0, vendorBodyModel);
        vendorsCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "FUCKING SUCCESS!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("response body", response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sending `@Body CustomObject obj` with `@Query` is not possible in Retrofit IMO. Instead you can use `RequestBody` type to send data. Refer this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398278/5180017) you'll find what you've been looking for. But the solution is in Kotlin change it according to your requirements. If it doesn't work, test your API with Postman and [edit] the question, post screenshots here. This way we can easily understand what's the problem with your code. Also don't forget to check the meaning of [400 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply create post model class like this:

```
class Body {
    Filters filters;
    int parameter2;
}

class Filters {
    VendorName VendorName;
    .......
    .......
    .......
}
```

and use it like this:

```
 @POST("api/Search/Vendor/Multiple")
    Call<String> getVendors(
            @Query("take") int take,
            @Query("page") int page,
            @Body Body json
    );
```

And also make sure that Body class field namings matches required namings, also dont forget that list or array is marked with `[...]`, simple pojo `{...}`

Here is full body class in Kotlin:

```
data class Body(
    @SerializedName("filters")
    val filters: Filters? = Filters()
)

data class Filters(
    @SerializedName("VendorName")
    val vendorName: VendorName? = VendorName()
)

data class VendorName(
    @SerializedName("value")
    val value: List<String?>? = listOf(),
    @SerializedName("cretiria")
    val cretiria: Int? = 0,
    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: Int? = 0
)
```

Comment: what did you mean about 'list or array'?

Comment: When trying to initialize your solution I got the following error "is not an enclosing class" - what am I missing?

Comment: @AlonShlider List or array is just a meaning of json formatting so you would not miss it. And "is not an enclosing class" is there because you need to finish up making Body class model, I just put it on the right understandable path :)

Comment: See updated answer, I did full Body class in Kotlin, Sorry don't have a time to refactor it, but it should be clear now.

Comment: I have updated my main post and did a Java implementation of your solution, yet the same error occurs. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Your code looks fine, it should work

Comment: It prints the 'Not successful' toast message with error code 400

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string create JsonObject and send it as `@Body JsonObject request`