# How to send JSON as Retrofit POST request

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to send a POST request in Retrofit for below JSON.

```
{"data":["dog playing football",45,256,256,2,5]}
```

I have sent the same request using Volley. Now I'm switching to Retrofit.

```
    val data = JSONObject()
    val arr = JSONArray()
    arr.put(inputText)
    arr.put(steps)
    arr.put(width)
    arr.put(height)
    arr.put(numberOfImages)
    arr.put(diversityScale)
    data.put("data", arr)
```

How can I send the same using Retrofit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST raw whole JSON in the body of a Retrofit request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request)

Comment: Retrofit tends to reconstruct your Json. It is best to create an object and send the object as the body.

Comment: @JiteshPrajapati i already tried that but it didn't worked. But converting to object works for me. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case  you can use like this :

```
   val data = JSONObject()
    val arr = JSONArray()
    arr.put(inputText)
    arr.put(steps)
    arr.put(width)
    arr.put(height)
    arr.put(numberOfImages)
    arr.put(diversityScale)
    data.put("data", arr)

val map = ObjectMapper().readValue<MutableMap<Any, Any>>(data.toString())


@POST("your_url_here")
Call<Object> yourFunName(@Body Map<String, String> body)
```