# How to specify a different name for json key while using Retrofit + Moshi

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I need to make a POST request to my backend with following json:

```
{
    start_time: 123456789
}
```

I have created the below data class for the body in Retrofit request:

```kotlin
data class MyRequestBody(
    @Json(name="start_time")
    val startTime: Long
)
```

But when I check on my backend the request contains the `startTime` field instead of `start_time`. How can I change the name of this variable for json serialization?

**Edit**:
My build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
```

My api interface:

```kotlin
internal interface RemoteTopicApi {

    @POST("xyz/")
    suspend fun getData(@Body body: MyRequestBody)

}
```

Retrofit Builder:

```kotlin
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Could you please point me to the exact answer. I checked this link but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: But `@SerializedName` is for Gson, right? I am using Moshi.

Comment: Are you sure that moshi is working fine with you ? because `@Json(name="start_time")` is enough to achieve what you want

Comment: Yeah, everything else is working fine, if I rename `startTime` to `start_time` it works as well but I want to stick to Kotlin conventions here.

Comment: Can you add the code for retrofit api call and retrofit instance initialization

Comment: Added. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Add those moshi dependencies:

```
// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'    
// Moshi
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.13.0'
kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0'
```

2- Change Retrofit Builder to this:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(
        Moshi.Builder()
            .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
    ))
    .build()
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! So, does this mean that the `@Json` annotation is useless without all this setup?

Comment: Well yes, this is the import for @Json `import com.squareup.moshi.Json`so it's part of `com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin` so without this dependency it's useless.
`com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi` doesn't contain all moshi features it's just used to link moshi with retrofit.

Comment: @ArpitShukla Kotlin's property doesn't see the annotation. You could do `@property:Json(...)`, but using the codegen is better, anyway.